# Differing polynomial GCDs over the field $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to find a mistake in my reasoning or calculations.

I have $$f(x)= x^4 + x^3 +6x^2 +x +1 \text{ and } 
g(x)= x^4 + 9x^3 + 6x^2 + x +3\\ \text{over the field } \mathbb{Z}_{11}.$$

My calculations are 
$$
f(x)=g(x)+3x^3 +6x +9\\
g(x)=(x^3+2x+3)(x+9) + 4x^2 +2x +9\\
x^3+2x+3 = (4x^2+2x+9)(3x+4) + 0
$$
resulting into $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=4x^2+2x+9$.

Yet an online calculator gives a different result $x^2+6x+5$ and I don't know what goes wrong.

Comment: Multiply your answer by $3$ (which is $4^{-1}$ mod $11$). What do you get?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   $4(x^2+6x+5)\equiv 4x^2+2x+9\bmod11$

Comment: @RichardD.James oups… I been resolving it for so long I lost all ability to notive things... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As it was kindly noticed in comments, my calculations were alright, but I totally forgot that I can get different answers because of the mod[11] (should've multiplied my own answer by 3 to get the same result as the online calculator).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009888/242) for a general discussion of **unit normalization** of gcds (I can't link it in the dupe list of the question since it has no upvotes yet)