# $\gcd(f,g) \neq 1 \iff \exists s,t \in F[x]: sf+tg=0 \wedge \deg(s) < \deg(g) \wedge \deg(t) < \deg(f)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

For "$\implies$" we know that the gcd can be written as a linear combination so there exist $k,l$ so that $kf+tg=\gcd(f,g)$. I thought of writing $kf+tg-\gcd(f,g)=0$ and then somehow find $s,t$ so we could get a linear combination of $f$ and $g$ that equates to $0$, however I wasn't able to do this and I also don't know how to use the fact that the gcd is not $1$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's trivial if $f=0$ or $g=0$. Else $\,sf+tg=0\iff \frac{f}g = \frac{-t}s.\,$ If the gcd  $\,d:=(f,g)\neq 1\,$ then $\,\deg(d)\ge 1\,$ so cancelling $\,d\,$ from $f,g$ reduces $\,f/g\,$ to a sought smaller $\,{-}t/s.\,$ Conversely if $f,g$ are coprime then there is no such smaller reduction since then by [unique fractionization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) $\,g\mid s\,$ so $\,\deg(s)\ge \deg(g)\,$  (the linked proof  also works for polynomials over a field since it only uses that gcds exist so Euclid's Lemma holds).

Comment: Equivalently, by unique fractionization, an equivalence class of fractions is exactly the set of all nonzero scalings $\,ca/(cb)\,$ of some fraction $\,a/b\,$ that is irreducible (reduced), i.e. $\, \gcd(a,b)\!=\!1.\,$ Thus $\,f/g :=ca/(cb)\,$ is reducible $\iff c =\gcd(f,g)\,$ has $\,\deg c\ge 1,\,$ i.e. $\gcd(f,g)\,$ is not a unit(= invertible), i.e. $\,\gcd(f,g)\neq 1\,$ (recall [unit gcds are normalized to $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009888/242) in $F[x]).\ \ $