# Finding $M$ such that $M*M*x*y$ modulo $2*z*M$ is 0?

Tags: number-theory

I have three variables $x,y,z$, but I want to find the smallest positive $M$ for which $M*M*x*y$ is divisible by $2*z*M$ which is the same as modulo 0. Can I do this without needing to brute check all values of $M$?

Comment: By $\ast$, do you mean multiplication?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2Mz$ divides $M^2xy$ if and only if $2z$ divides $Mxy$.  So the question is just: find the least positive $M$ such that $Mxy$ is divisible by $2z$.

But this can be rephrased as: find the least positive multiple of $xy$ that is also a multiple of $2z$.  So we want $Mxy = \mathop{\mathrm{lcm}} (xy, 2z)$; so the solution is: $$M = \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}(xy,2z)}{xy}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ 2zM\mid xyM^2\!\iff\! 2z\mid xy M\!\iff\! 2z\mid (xy,2z)M\!\iff\! \color{#C00}{2z/(xy,2z)}\mid M,\ \ \, $ (a,b) = gcd(a,b)

**Or:** $ $ said dually  $\rm\!\iff\! xy,2z\mid xyM\!\iff\!\, [xy,2z]\mid xyM\!\iff\!\, \color{#0A0}{[xy,2z]/xy}\mid M,\ \ \ [a,b] = lcm(a,b)$

They're equivalent by the [$\rm\,gcd * lcm\:$ formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) $\rm\ ab = (a,b)[a,b] = gcd(a,b)\,lcm(a,b),\ $ so

$$\rm  (xy,2z)[xy,2z]\, =\, xy\,2z\ \ \Rightarrow\ \color{#C00}{\dfrac{2z}{(xy,2z)}}\, =\, \color{#0A0}{\dfrac{[xy,2z]}{xy}}$$

**Remark** $\ $ You can find many more examples of such *universal* proofs of gcd and lcm properties in my prior posts. Learning these techniques makes the proofs *mechanical,* just like calculus makes calculating volumes mechanical.