# Divisors of a product.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof that if $d \mid mn$, where $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then $d=d_1d_2$ where $d_1 \mid m$ and $d_2 \mid n$, where the  $d_i$ are comprime?

I was working on Project Euler and came across this fact but the link to the proof had expired.

Comment: Any condition on $d_i$'s?

Comment: Yes, they are coprime. See [this link](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-21-sum-of-amicable-pairs/)

Comment: @DemetriP If $d_i$ must be coprime, then you need a condition on $m$ and $n$.  Else take $d=4$, $m=n=2$.

Comment: 6|6.5, 6=3.2 but neither 3|5 nor 2|5.

Comment: My mistake, m and n are also comprime.

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande In your example, pick $6=6\cdot1$ instead of $3\cdot 2$.  The question doesn't say it holds for all possible $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Comment: This is actually true without any coprimality condition (for instance, $d_1 = (d,m)$ and $d_2 = d/d_1$ works), which gives a stronger statement than the one in the question (if $m$ and $n$ are coprime then any divisors of $m$ and $n$ are necessarily coprime).  However, adding coprimality additionally makes the choice of $d_1$, $d_2$ unique.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $(d,m)$.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\color{#c00}{cd = mn}\,\Rightarrow\, (d,m)(d,n) = ((d,m)d,(d,\color{#c00}m)\color{#c00}n) = (d,\color{#0a0}{m,n},\color{#c00}c)\color{#c00}d = d,\,$ by $\color{#0a0}{(m,n)=1}$

Hence $\ d = (d,m)(d,n)\ $ where $\ (d,m)\mid m,\,\ (d,n)\mid n\ \ \ $ **QED**

---

**Or**  $\,\ d\mid mn\iff d\mid dn,mn \color{#c0f}\iff d\mid (dn,mn)\overset{\color{#0a0}{\rm D\,L}} = (d,m)n \iff d/(d,m)\mid n$

Therefore $\ d\, =\, (d,m) \dfrac{d}{(d,m)}  \ $ where $\ (d,m)\mid m\ $ and $\ \dfrac{d}{(d,m)}\mid  n\ \ \ $ **QED**

Above we used $\, d\mid j,k\color{#c0f}\iff d\mid (j,k),\,$ the [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) of the gcd, and we also used $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{DL} =$ the [gcd Distributive Law,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785465/let-a-and-b-be-non-zero-integers-and-c-be-an-integer-let-d-hcfa-b/785544#785544) both here and in the first proof.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $(d,m)$.  What does it mean?

Comment: @DemetriP $\ (x,y) := \gcd(x,y)\,$ is standard notation in number theory. $\ \ $

Comment: Great, thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The case where $m = n = 1$ is trivial.

Since $d \mid mn,$ we have
$d = p_{1}^{a_{1}}\cdots p_{k}^{a_{k}}$ for some integer $k \geq 1$, some integers $a_{1}, \dots, a_{k} \geq 0,$ and some distinct primes $p_{1}, \dots, p_{k}$ such that $p_{j} \mid m$ or $p_{j} \mid n$ for all $1 \leq j \leq k.$
Suppose that $p_{1}^{a_{1}}, \dots, p_{i}^{a_{i}} \mid m$ and $p_{i+1}^{a_{i+1}}, \dots, p_{k}^{a_{k}} \mid n$ for some $1 \leq i \leq k.$ 
Let
$d_{1} := p_{1}^{a_{1}}\cdots p_{i}^{a_{i}}$ and $d_{2} := p_{i+1}^{a_{i+1}}\cdots p_{k}^{a_{k}}$. Then we see that $(d_{1}, d_{2}) = 1,$ that $d = d_{1}d_{2},$ that $d_{1} \mid m,$ and that $d_{2} \mid n.$

Comment: I am glad it helps.

Comment: @OP Notice $\,d_1 = (d,m)\,$ and $\,d_2 = (d,n)\,$ as in my answer. The hypothesis $\,(m,n)=1\,$ is not needed, see the 2nd proof there.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Okay, thanks. If it was you that downvoted my answer, did you downvote it simply because of a redundant hypothesis?

Comment: I did not downvote any answers here so I don't know the answer to that.