# Prove that $g(x,y) = \gcd(x,y)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Define a function $g: \mathbb{N}_0\;\times\;\mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$

Let it have such properties:

**1)** $g(x,y) = g(y,x)$

**2)** $g(x,y) = x$, if and only if $y$ is divisible by $x$

**3)** $g(g(x,y), z) = g(x, g(y,z))$

Prove that $g(x,y) = \gcd(x,y)$

Intuitively I understand that GCD has all these same properties but I guess that it is not enough. In general showing that one function is the same as another one, we must prove that these functions have same value on all possible sets of arguments. Please, show me how to prove such facts in formal way.

Comment: Why was the previous question deleted and reposted? To quote the previous commenters: Counterexample: $g(x,y) = \min \{x,y\}$

Comment: Link to previous deleted question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3833129/42969. –

Comment: @player3236: It was mention in the comments to that other question that $g(x,y) = \min \{x,y\}$ does not satisfy (2) with $y=0$.

Comment: @player3236 counter example to your counter example: min{2,7} = 2 but 7 is not divisible by 2

Comment: The [proof-writing] tag is for questions about the formulation of a proof, not generally for questions asking for a proof of a statement.

Comment: That is not a counterexample since the behaviour of $g$ is not defined for "$y$ not divisible by $x$". On the other hand, I remember the previous comments mentioned a possible circumvention of the case with zeroes. Perhaps take the $\max$ for those cases instead.

Comment: It suffices to show $g(x,y)\divides x,y$ and $z\divides x,y\implies z=g(x,y)$. Hint: to show $g(x,y)\divides x$ it suffices to show $g(g(x,y),x)=g(x,y)$.

Comment: Actually should condition 2 be if and only if?

Comment: Because as it is written, $g(x,y)=\min(x,y)$ is a valid counterexample. That is we can have $g(2,7)=2$ even though 2 does not divide 7.

Comment: @Couchy yes, you are right. I meant "if and only if", edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show that some number $N$ is $\gcd(x,y)$ then you need to show two things:

1. $N$ divides $x$ and $y$.
2. If some other number $z$ divides $x$ and $y$ then $z\leq N$.

So you should try to show these two things for $N=g(x,y)$.

For example, we can verify that $g(x,y)$ divides $x$ and $y$. First $g(x,g(x,y))=g(g(x,x),y)$ by (3). So $g(x,g(x,y))=g(x,y)$ by (2). So $g(g(x,y),x)=g(x,y)$ by (1). So $x$ is divisible by $g(x,y)$ by (2). You can do a similar argument to show $g(x,y)$ divides $y$.

So now suppose some other number $z$ divides $x$ and $y$. We want to show $z\leq g(x,y)$. Actually, we'll show $z$ divides $g(x,y)$. By (2) $g(z,x)=z=g(z,y)$. So by (3) we get
$g(z,g(x,y))=g(g(z,x),y)=g(z,y)=z$. So $z$ divides $g(x,y)$ by (2).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \color{#c00}{z\mid x}\Rightarrow\, \underbrace{(z,(x,y))}_{\!\!\!\!\textstyle ((\color{#c00}{z,x}),y)} = (\color{#0a0}{z,y})\ $
so $\, \begin{align} \color{#0a0}{z\:\!\mid\:\! y}&\Rightarrow z\mid (x,y)\\
                     z\!=\!x    &\Rightarrow (x,y)\mid x\\[.2em] \end{align}\,$
so $\ \underbrace{\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{z\mid x,y\iff z\mid (x,y)}_{\phantom{1_1}}\!\!\!\!\!}_{\textstyle\text{i.e. $(x,y)$ is a gcd of $x,y$}_{\phantom{1_1}}\!\!\!\!}$
**Remark** $\,\ (x,y)\mid x\Rightarrow\,(x,y)\mid y\,$ by symmetry and commutativity. In more detail:
$\quad\,{\begin{align}
\!z\mid \color{#0a0}x,\color{#c00}y\Rightarrow\  &(z,(x,y))\overset{3} = ((z,\color{#0a0}x),y)\overset{2} = \overbrace{(z,\color{#c00}y)}^{\textstyle z}\,\overset{2}\Rightarrow\, z\mid (x,y)\\[.5em]
z\!=\!x\, \ \ \ \Rightarrow\ &\! (x,(x,y)) = ((x,x),y) = (x,y)\underset{2,\,1}\Rightarrow\, (x,y)\mid x,[\![\:\!y\ \ \text{too by symmetry}\,]\!]\\[,2em]
\end{align}}$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) for the universal definition of GCD & LCM.