# Defining additions in the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to describe all possible ways in which one can define additions in the set of integers to give it a structure of ring when the multiplication is same as the usual multiplication ?

If the addition is same as the usual addition then one can easily describe all possible multiplications. What can we say when multiplication is usual ?

Comment: When you don't fix any structure, you just have a countable set. There is not much to say.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Yeah, I understand that there is not much to say about the general case. Can we say something when multiplication is usual ?

Answer (score 3):

I assert the multiplicative structure of the integers is completely characterized by these three properties:

- There are exactly two units: the square roots of unity
- A unique factorization domain
- Has countably infinitely many prime elements

So any ring with these three properties is isomorphic to the integers with non-standard addition, and conversely any non-standard addition defined on the integers gives a ring with these three properties.

Some examples of rings with these properties are:

- Any polynomial ring over the integers
- Any polynomial ring over the finite field of 3 elements
- Any polynomial ring over the ring of integers in an imaginary quadratic number field of class number 1 that is neither $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ nor $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: Is there a classification of all such rings? I mean can you explicitly give me a list of all possible rules of multiplications?

Comment: The above is a classification of all such rings. :) But I know what you're asking, and I expect it to either be unfeasible or it has a simple answer that requires more arithmetic geometry than I know.

Comment: Nit-pick: a couple of those imaginary quadratic extensions with class number 1 have more than two units.

Comment: Argh. I think every version of that last bullet I had written down carefully avoided those two cases, except for the one I actually posted. :(

Answer (score 3):

As Hurkly mentioned, this amounts to finding rings whose multiplicative monoid is isomorphic to that of the ring of integers, which is freely generated by the primes, and by the [Conway prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1175403/242) $\,-1,$ of order $\,2$. Thus one seeks UFDs with two units and countably many primes. It is easy to find examples among well-known examples of UFDs (polynomial rings, number fields, etc).

Many properties of domains are purely multiplicative so can be described in terms of monoid structure. Let R be a domain with fraction field K. Let R* and K* be the 
multiplicative groups of units of R and K respectively. Then 
G(R), the *divisibility group* of R, is the factor group K*/R*.

- R is a UFD $\iff$ G(R) $\:\rm\cong \mathbb Z^{\,I}\:$ is a sum of copies of $\rm\:\mathbb Z\:.$
- R is a gcd-domain $\iff$ G(R) is lattice-ordered (lub{x,y} exists)
- R is a valuation domain $\iff$ G(R) is linearly ordered
- R is a Riesz domain $\iff$ G(R) is a Riesz group, i.e. 
  an ordered group satisfying the Riesz interpolation property: if  $\rm\:a,b \le c,d\:$  then  $\rm\:a,b \le x \le c,d\:$  for some $\rm\:x\:.\:$ A domain $\rm\:R\:$ is  Riesz if every element is [primal,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63323/how-to-use-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic-to-conclude-that-gcdak-bn-1-f/63330#63330) i.e. $\rm\:A\:|\:BC\ \Rightarrow\ A = bc,\ b\:|\:B,\ c\:|\:C,\:$ for some $\rm b,c\in R.$

For more on divisibility groups see the following surveys:

J.L. Mott. Groups of divisibility: A unifying concept for 
integral domains and partially ordered groups, Mathematics 
and its Applications, no. 48, 1989, pp. 80-104.

J.L. Mott. The group of divisibility and its applications, 
Conference on Commutative Algebra (Univ. Kansas, Lawrence, Kan., 
1972), Springer, Berlin, 1973, pp. 194-208. Lecture Notes in Math., 
Vol. 311. MR 49 #2712