# Show that the relation defined on an integral domain by "$x\sim y$" ("$x$ is associated with $y$") is a relation of equivalence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

I did the following demonstration: Would it be possible to give me a feedbak if i'm to wrong.

Be $A$ an integral domain and $x,y \in A$, then: 
$x\sim y \Rightarrow$ $\exists u \in \mathfrak{U}(A)$ such that $y=xu \Rightarrow x \mid y$ and $y\mid x$. So there's $a,b \in A$ such that $xa=y$ and $yb=x$.

$1º$ case: $x=0.$

$x=0$ and $xa=y \Rightarrow y=0.$

Take $u=1 \in \mathfrak{U}(A)$ and then,
$0=0\cdot 1$, or $y=xu$.

$2º$ case: $a\neq 0$.

$xa=y$ and $yb=x$.
$\Rightarrow xab=x$
$\Rightarrow x(ab-1)=0$
$\Rightarrow ab=1$
$\Rightarrow a$ is invertible.

Taking $u=a \in \mathfrak{U}(A)$ and then $xu=y$.
By hypothesis, $y=xu$, $u \in \mathfrak{U}(A)$. It follows that $x\mid y.$ In addition, from $y=xu$, we have $y \cdot u^{-1}=x$ and then $ y\mid x$.

So, $x\sim y$.

$\square$

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to show. You've structured your argument as an if and only if, but you seem to showing that $x $~$y$ if and only if $x,y$ are associate, but this is how you define ~?

Comment: @NoahSolomon I corrected my statement. It is not if and only if.

Comment: Perhaps I am a little slow on the pickup today, but from what I can tell you start by assuming that $x$ ~ $y$ and end by concluding $x$ ~ $y$, so again I'm not sure what you're trying to show. I posted an answer explaining how I would answer what I think you're trying to prove.

Comment: @NoahSolomon I really want to prove $x\sim y$, but on the ring of integrity. It is more advanced than showing the equivalence relation.

Comment: You want to prove that $x$~$y$ given what initial assumption?

Comment: @NoahSolomon, yes... I want to prove that given an integral domain, then there exist $x\sim y$

Comment: @Noah Usually domains are hypothesized to be commutative rings **with $1$**  etc (esp. when studying divisibility theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds not only for the unit group but for any subgroup $G$ of the multiplicative group, i.e.

suppose that $\,G\subset A^{\times}\,$ satisfies $\,\color{#c00}1\in G\,$ and $\,g,h\in G\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#08f}{gh}\in G,\,$ and $\, \color{#0a0}{g^{-1}}\in G$.

Note $\ x\approx y \!\overset{\rm def\!\!}\iff\! x = g\, y\ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ g\in G\ $ is an equivalence relation, $ $  since

$\qquad\ \ \ \  \approx\,$ is $\ \ \rm\color{#c00}{reflexive}\,\ \ $ by $\  x = \color{#c00}1x\,\Rightarrow\, x\approx x$

$\qquad\ \ \ \  \approx\,$ is $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{symmetric}\,$ by $\ x\approx y\,\Rightarrow\, x = g y\,\Rightarrow\, y = \color{#0a0}{g^{-1}}x\,\Rightarrow\,y\approx x$

$\qquad\ \ \ \ \approx\,$ is $\ \rm\color{#08f}{transitive}\,\ $  by $\,x\approx y\approx z\,\Rightarrow\, y = hz,\,  x = g y = g(hz) = (\color{#08f}{gh})z\,\Rightarrow\, x\approx z$

**Remark** $\ G x = \{ gx\, :\, g\in G\}\ $ is called the $G$-*orbit* of $x.\, $ It is a basic concept in group theory.

A quick way to recognize such group structure is by the [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test), i.e. a nonempty $G\subset H$ of a group $H$ forms a group $\iff$ it is closed under division, i.e. $\, g,h\in g\,\Rightarrow g/h = gh^{-1}\in G,\,$ which is clear for units.

When studying divisibility it is often useful to ignore units by factoring out the unit group, e.g. see the [divisibility group](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180717/242) and  its associated characterizations of UFDs and gcd, valuation and Reisz domains mentioned there.

Comment: @BillDubaque, when should I use the demonstration I made?

Comment: @Fernando You haven't shown that it is an equivalence relation, i.e. that it satisfies the above three properties.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to show in your exposition. To answer the question in the title, i.e. show that a relation ~ is an equivalence relation, we need to show three things, reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.

Reflexivity is clear, every element is associate to itself since $x = 1 \cdot x \forall x \in R$.

Symmetry is also easy since units are invertible, so if $x$~$y$ then there exists some unit $u$ such that $x = uy$ so $u^{-1}x=y$ i.e. $y$ ~ $x$.

Lastly we consider transitivity. Suppose $x$ ~ $y$ and $y$~$z$. Then there exist units $u,v$ such that $x = uy$ and $y = vz$. So we have that $x = uvz$. Since the units are closed under multiplication, $x$~$z$ as desired.