# Show $(a,bc)=(a,b)(a,c)$ if $(b,c)=1$ [or $(a,b,c)= 1]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

*Problem:* Show that if $(b,c)=1$, then for any integer $a$ we have $(a,bc)=(a,b)(a,c)$. [*Hint:* Prove that each member of the alleged equation divides the other.]

This is the way I proved it (without the hint):
$(a,b)(a,c)=(a(a,b),c(a,b))=(a^2,ab,ac,bc)=(a^2,bc,a(b,c))=(a^2,a,bc)=((a^2,a),bc)=(a,bc)$

But how should I prove it using that hint or at least a similar proof.

Comment: I give a (somewhat long, probably far from optimal) proof using your hint in *18.781 (Spring 2016): Floor and arithmetic functions* ( http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/floor.pdf ) (proof of Proposition 1.2.10). That said, your proof is a lot nicer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof can be done more efficiently as below. More generally see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6657/242)

$(a,b)(a,c) = (aa,ab,ac,bc) = (a\color{#c00}{(a,b,c)},bc) = (a,bc),\ $ by $\ (b,c)=1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{(a,b,c)= 1}$

where we used [GCD polynomial arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242), i.e. associative, commutative, distributive laws.

---

To use the hint [reduce to case $\,(\bar a,\bar b)\!=\!1\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3471852/242) via cancel $\,\color{#0a0}{d \!=\! (a,b)}\,$ from both sides to get equivalent

$$ (\bar a,\bar bc) = (a,c),\ \ \  \bar a = a/d,\, \bar b = b/d$$

$d\mid \bar a,\bar bc\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid \bar a\mid a\ $ & $\ d\mid \bar ac,\bar bc\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid (\bar ac,\bar bc)=(\bar a,\bar b)c = c\,$ so $\,d\mid a,c$.
$d\mid a,c\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid c\mid \bar bc\ $ & $\ d\mid\!\overbrace{\!\!\bar ad,\!\!\!}^{\large a}\,\bar ac\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid (\bar ad,\bar ac)=\bar a(\color{#0a0}d,c)=\bar a\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}{a,b},c)}^{\large \color{#c00}{=\,\bf  1}}=\bar a$ so $\,d\mid \bar a,\bar bc$

So $\,\bar a ,\bar bc\,$ and $\,a,c\,$ have the same common divisors $\,d,\,$ so the same *greatest* common divisor.

---

**Or** more directly [as here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242) $\,(\bar a,\bar b c) = (\bar a,\bar a c,\bar bc) = (\bar a,(\bar a,\bar b)c) = (\bar a,c)$.

Comment: When cancelling $\,d\,$ we used $\,(a,bc) = d(a/d,(b/d)c) = d(\bar a,\bar b c)$ by the [gcd Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)