# Calculate ideal product $(2,x)(3,x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

$I=(2,x)$ and $J=(3,x)$ be ideals.

$I\cdot J=(6,x)$.

Because $6=2\cdot 3$ and $x=3\cdot x-2\cdot x$, does this means that $I\cdot J$ contains $(6,x)$ or is it the inverse?

Comment: Well, the last sentence of the post means that $I \cdot J \supset (6,x)$. To deduce that $I \cdot J \subset (6,x)$ we can check that all products of generators of $I$ and $J$ are in $(6,x)$.

Comment: @user26857 6 and x can be expressed as a linear combination of elements of J and I? Is it so?

Comment: I think you proved this. In fact, they are linear combinations of *products* of elements from $I$ and $J$.

Comment: Also it is usually nice to mention what ring you are working with since the ideal generated in $\mathbb{Q}$ for example would be $(1)$

Answer (score 2):

$IJ=(2\cdot 3,2x,3x,x^2)$. But $x=3x-2x\in IJ$, so $IJ=(6,2x,3x,x^2,x)=(6,x)$.

Comment: ok now I understand a bit more

Comment: so this means that $IJ$ contains (6,x). The proof of the inverse is more difficult I think, that is (6,x) contains IJ?

Comment: Did you notice that I've used $=$ everywhere?

Comment: yes i noticed of course

Comment: Then why I ask about the "converse"? There is no converse left to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the product ideals below using [ideal arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242) (esp. *distributive law*)

yields $\,(2,x)(3,x) = (6,2x,3x,xx) = (6,x(\color{#c00}{2,3},x)) = (6,x)\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{(2,3)=1}$

**Generally**, $ $ as for gcds, $ $  $(a,c)(b,c) = (ab,c(\color{#c00}{a,b,c})) = (ab,c)\,$ if $\,\color{#c00}{(a,b,c) = 1}$

**Note** on notation: when we view $\:\!\color{#c00}1\:\!$ an *ideal* (e.g. in above ideal equalities), we use the convention that this denotes the unit ideal $\:\!\color{#c00}{(1)}.\,$ This allows us to write proofs like above that work uniformly for both ideals and gcds, e.g. see [these proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) of Euclid's Lemma (cf. comments below).

Comment: The proof shows more generally $\,(a,b,c)=1\Rightarrow (a,c)(b,c) = (ab,c)\,\ $ [[same](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1886026/242) for gcds]

Comment: @Bill Dubuque so if the ideals were (2,x) and (4,x) because the gcd(2,4) is not one, it woul d have been different?

Comment: @pollaris See my prior comment. In particular, $(a,b,c) = (2,4,x)\neq (1)$ so the inference my first comment does not apply to your example. It should be clear from the proof that "$1$" denotes the unit ideal.