# What is the ideal $(x,y)^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am reading this [article](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/Publications/ggt05-hauser.pdf) and in page 6 there is an exercise to show that the ideals $(x,y)$ and $(x,y)^2$ define the same blowup of the affine space $A^2$ when taken as a center.

I have two questions:

What exactly is the ideal $(x,y)^2$? I would like to understand who are the elements of this ideal.

Also, I would appreciate some hint about how to solve this exercise. Maybe considering that the two of them define the same zero locus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition of $(x,y)^2=(x,y)(x,y)$ is all finite sums of products of pairs of elements of $(x,y)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Ideal_operations). You can present it by giving generators as $(x^2,xy, y^2)$.

Comment: See e.g [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4451975/242) for how to calculate such ideal products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product of two ideals $I$ and $J$ is the ideal $IJ$ generated by all products $ab$, where $a \in I$ and $b \in J$.

The square of an ideal $I$ is the ideal $I^2 = II$. So it is generated by all products $ab$, where $a,b \in I$.

The ideal $(x,y)$ in the ring $K[x,y]$ is generated by $x$ and $y$. So $(x,y)^2$ is generated by $x^2$, $xy$, and $y^2$.