# Proof of Euclid's lemma using fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, prime-factorization

I want a proof of Euclid's theorem (if p is prime and p|(a.b) where a and b are integers, then either p|a or p|b) using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.  I already understand the proof assuming p is not |a and using gcd(p,a). I want a proof that rely's on FTofA.  Searching on line I can find examples of using Euclid's lemma to prove Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic but I want to go the other direction, and assuming Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, prove Euclid's lemma.

Comment: You mean the Fundamental *Axiom* of Arithmetic if you haven't proven Euclid's Lemma yet.

Comment: Trivial: Let $a=\prod p_i^{v_i}$ be the unique factorization of $a$ and $\prod q_j^{w_j}$ be the unique factorization of $b$.  So $ab =\prod p_i^{v_i} \prod q_j^{w_j}$ and as $p|ab$, $p$ must be one of $\{p_i\}$ in which case $p|a$ or $p$ must be one of $\{q_i\}$ in which case $p|b$.  That was trivial.  *BUT* you can't know that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is true if you haven't prove Euclid's Lemma first.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be prime and $a,b$ integers with $p|ab$.

This means that there is an integer $k$ such that $pk=ab$. Writing out the prime factorisations of $a,b$ and $k$, we have left and right of the equal sign a decomposition in prime factors and uniqueness of prime factorisation tells us that $p$ is a prime in the prime factorisation of either $a$ or $b$. In particular, $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ we sketch a proof of the  *general* Euclid's lemma $\rm\,\gcd(a,b)=1,\ a\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid c\,$ from [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242)

$\rm\, a\mid bc\:$ so $\rm\:ad = bc\:$ for some $\rm\:d.\:$ By  *existence* we can factor all four terms into prime factors, and by *uniqueness* the same multiset of primes occurs on both sides. So all of the primes in the factorization of $\rm\:a\:$ must also occur on RHS, necessarily in the factorization of $\rm\:c,\:$ by $\,\rm \gcd(a,b)\!=\!1$. Thus $\rm\:a\mid c\:$ since all of its prime factors (counting multiplicity) occur in $\rm\:c.\:$

**Remark** $ $ The inference is (multi)set-theoretic:  $\rm\: A\cap B = \{\,\},\ \ A \cup D\,=\, B\cup C\:$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:A\subset C,\:$ where $\rm\:A =$ multiset of primes in the unique prime factorization of $\rm\:A,\:$ and similarly  for $\rm\:B,C,D.$

Well worth knowing (& proving!) is the following *primal* generalization from primes to composites

**Prime Divisor Property**  $\rm\quad p\ |\ a\:b\ \Rightarrow\ p\:|\:a\ $ or $\rm\ p\:|\:b,\ $ for all primes $\rm\:p\,;\:\: $ more generally

**Primal Divisor Property**  $\rm\ \ \: c\ |\ a\:b\ \Rightarrow\ c_1\, |\: a\:,\: $ $\rm\ c_2\:|\:b\,\ \ \&\,\ \  c = c_1\:c_2,\ $ for all $\rm\:c$

The latter property may be considered to be a generalization of the prime divisor property from atoms (irreducibles) to composites (one easily checks that atoms are  primal $\Leftrightarrow$ prime). This way leads to various *refinement-based* views of unique factorization, e.g. via [Schreier refinement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/basic-divisibility-fact/6657#6657) and [Riesz interpolation,](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ehb3/publ/euk-2.pdf) the Euclid-Euler [Four Number Theorem](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ehb3/publ/euk-1.pdf) (Vierzahlensatz), etc, which prove more natural in noncommutative rings - see  Paul Cohn's 1973 Monthly survey [Unique Factorization Domains.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319253)

Comment: Note: in a completely *rigorous* proof one should be sure to *explicitly* mention *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations in *every* place that it is used.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial.

Let $a=\prod p_i^{v_i}$ be the unique prime factorization of $a$ and $b=\prod q_j^{w_j}$ be the unique prime factorization of $b$.  So $ab =\prod p_i^{v_i} \prod q_j^{w_j}$ is the unique prime factorization of $ab$.

And if $p|ab$, $p$ must be either one of the $\{p_i\}$ which would mean $p|a$, or $p$ must be one of the $\{q_j\}$ which would mean $p|b$.

But how can you know the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is true in the first place?  That is an essential question and can not be ignored.

Comment: I didn't check the proof, but even the wikipedia entry on the fundamental theorem offers a proof without Euclid's lemma. That being said, how does your answer differ from mine?

Comment: Alternatively, this theorem follows from Jordan-Holder's theorem but this might be overkill.

Comment: FTA need not be proven with Euclid's lemma but Euclid's lemma is always simpler and more fundamental than FTA which is really a generalization of EL.  This is like using trigonometry to prove Euclid's 5 postulate.

Comment: I was just referring to your comment above : "By (E) at least one of the respective sub sigma algebras must be infinite."

Comment: This is the best explanation of the 3.  Thank you.