# Question regarding floor() function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given x is a real number and c is a natural number. Prove that:

```
floor( floor(x) / c ) = floor( x / c )
```

When x > 0, I can prove it by let x = n + z where 0 < z < 1.
Then rhs = floor( n/c + z/c ) which equals to floor( floor(x) ) since z/c -> 0.
However, when x < 0, it's wrong when letting x = -( n + z ). Because it always give me a smaller negative number. Is my logic wrong here?  Any hint?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: I suspect that you want $x=-n+z$ (no parentheses around $n+z$) as, for instance, $\text{floor}(-1.5)=-2$.

Comment: @Issac: Thanks, so if `x = -1.67` then I would rewrite it as: `-2 + 0.33`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it here:

- http://chandrumath.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/more-on-the-floor-function/

Comment: @Chandru1: Thanks but you spoiled me :(!

Comment: @chan: Sorry chan.

Comment: This post no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is the special case $\rm\ m = 1\ $ in a proof I [presented here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6748/adjoint-functors/6793#6793). See that thread for more on the *universal* viewpoint that explains the simplicity of this proof. For convenience, here is the proof.

**LEMMA** $\rm\: \  \lfloor x/(mn)\rfloor\ =\ \lfloor{\lfloor x/m\rfloor}/n\rfloor\ \  $
for $\rm\ \ n > 0$

**Proof** $\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \ k\ \le \lfloor{\lfloor x/m\rfloor}/n\rfloor$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\iff\quad\ \ k\ \le\ \:{\lfloor x/m\rfloor}/n$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\iff\ \ nk\ \le\ \ \lfloor x/m\rfloor$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\iff\ \ nk\ \le\:\ \ \ x/m$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\iff\ \ \ \ k\ \le\:\ \ \ x/(mn)$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\iff\ \ \ \  k\ \le\ \ \lfloor x/(mn)\rfloor $

Compare the above trivial proof to more traditional proofs, e.g. the [special case $\rm\ m = 1\ $ here.](http://chandrumath.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/more-on-the-floor-function/)

Comment: Many thanks for a great solution. Very clever and succinct ;) !

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with equation ⌊⌊a⌋/b⌋=c
2. replace outermost floor with (c ≤ ⌊a⌋/b)
3. multiply by b (cb ≤ ⌊a⌋)
4. this is the same as (cb ≤ a)
5. (I left out a constraint on the right (easier for me))

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 you are encouraged to use mathjax on this site.

Comment: i think i am wrong, should just be (cb ≤ a < cb+1)