# Excessive use of the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, alternative-proof, yoneda-lemma

In [a MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts) on "nuking mosquitos", [Andrej Bauer](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1176/andrej-bauer) offered [the following proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts/42535#42535):

> If two elements in a poset have the same lower bounds then they are equal by Yoneda lemma.

I understand that a poset can be considered to be a category with at most one arrow between any two objects, and I understand the statement of the Yoneda lemma, although I have little experience in using it.  But I do not understand this proof. How does the Yoneda Lemma help?

Comment: The [silly] tag is... silly.

Comment: For some related examples in posts here, see the [floor function](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/147832/242) and [gcds and lcms.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/147900/242)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained in [my blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/the-yoneda-lemma-i/) on the Yoneda lemma.

By the way, I do not consider this argument "nuking mosquitos." The Yoneda lemma is hardly a nuke; I would reserve that term for a highly technical result which requires a long proof. The proof of the Yoneda lemma is extraordinarily short and elegant. Besides, even this seemingly trivial special case can be surprisingly useful.

Comment: The nuke isn’t specifically the Yoneda lemma: it’s employing the wholly unnecessary language and machinery of category theory to prove a trivial result that follows immediately from the definition (each is a lower bound of the other, and the order is antisymmetric). Possibly it’s useful to see this fact as an instance of something more general $-$ I’m agnostic on that point $-$ and perhaps the machinery is something less than a nuke, but it’s certainly using a bulldozer to move a chickpea.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating (here or in you blog) a bit more how went from set-theoretic presheaves to 2-valued presheaves? Did you embed 2 into $\operatorname{Set}$? I understand that once you realise that a presheaf can be identified with a downward closed set, and a representable presheaf corresponds to $D_y$, that you get the result - but I don't understand how the presheaves look like originally, meaning before we consider them as functors from $P^{\operatorname{op}}$ to $2$.

Comment: @Sha: yes, $2$ embeds into $\text{Set}$ as the full subcategory on $\{ 0, 1 \}$ (where $0$ is the initial object / the empty set and $1$ is the terminal object / the one-element set). The Yoneda embedding of a preorder canonically takes values in this full subcategory.

Comment: Right, thanks! I got a bit confused when you worked with $2$, so I wrote it out in the 'general notation', and now I see it; the point is that each hom-set is either empty or not (consisting of one element).