# Symbolic Notation for Least Common Multiple

Tags: logic, symbolic-computation

I am trying to write a proof for the least common multiple lcm(x, y), where lcm(x,y), x, and y are of course integers. What are the properties of lcm(x,y) written symbolically in mathematical logic notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are dual *universal* definitions of $\rm\,lcm\,$ and $\rm\,gcd\,$ that work in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ (or any integral domain).

**Definition** of **LCM** $\quad$ If $\quad\rm a,b\:|\:c \;\iff\; [a,b]\:|\:c \quad\;$ then $\quad\rm [a,b] \;$ is an **LCM** of $\:\rm a,b$

**Definition** of **GCD** $\quad$ If $\quad\rm c\:|\:a,b \;\iff\; c\:|\:(a,b) \quad$ then $\quad\rm (a,b) \;$ is an **GCD** of $\:\rm a,b$

Note that $\;\rm a,b\:|\:[a,b] \;$ follows by putting $\;\rm c = [a,b] \;$ in the definition. Dually $\;\rm (a,b)|\:a,b \:.$

These definitions are equivalent to the more specific notions employed in Euclidean domains.

If you know a little category theory then you may recognize the definitions as special cases of (co)products. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/147900/242) for further discussion. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149376/242) for viewpoints from adoints and Yoneda's Lemma, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147832/242) for an analogy: the $\rm\,floor\,$ funciton as a right adjoint. Compare the proof there to the proof below.

Such universal $\iff$ definitions frequently enable one to give slick proofs that concisely unify both arrow directions, e.g. consider the following proof of the fundamental $\rm\,lcm * gcd\,$ identity.

**Theorem**  $\rm\;\; (a,b)\, =\, ab/[a,b] \;\;$  if $\;\rm\ [a,b] \;$  exists.

**Proof** $\rm\quad\ d\:|\:a,b \iff a,b\:|\:ab/d \iff [a,b]\:|\:ab/d \iff d\:|\:ab/[a,b] \quad$ **QED**

Comment: At the level where this is a relevant exercise, I think abbreviating "$(a\mid c)\land (b\mid c)$" as "$a,b\mid c$" would be Frowned Upon (and similarly $c\mid a,b$ for $(c\mid a)\land (c\mid b)$) -- particularly because the OP seems to have it posed as an exercise in symbolic logic rather than one of number theory.

Comment: @Henning I understand your point, but I think it is essential to choose notation that highlights the innate structure. Writing everything out in first-order logic only serves to obfuscate such.

Comment: x @Bill: well, yes -- except if (as I strongly suspect is the case here) the point of the exercise is to train the skill of "writing everything out in first-order logic" _itself_. (Knowing _how_ to do that is useful and enlightening, even though actually _doing_ it is in most practical cases pointless). The OP did tag his question [logic], after all.

Comment: @Henning It certainly would help if the OP provided more context. It could be number theory used as an example for a logic exercise, or it could be a true question in number theory, whose goal is to understand the foundations (or logic) of lcm and gcd.

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers $x, y$, the least common multiple $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ may be uniquely described by the following (using $\mid$ for the "divides" relation (in fact, ordering) ):

$$\forall z: x \mid z \land y \mid z \implies \operatorname{lcm}(x,y) \mid z$$

If you are familiar with this language, this observataion can be expressed by saying that $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ is the least upper bound, or *supremum* of $x$ and $y$ in the poset $(\Bbb N, \mid)$. Similarly, $\operatorname{gcd}(x,y)$ is the infimum of $x$ and $y$.