# Can the identity $ab=\gcd(a,b)\text{lcm}(a,b)$ be recovered from this category?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, category-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Define the category $\mathcal{C}$ as follows. The objects are defined as $\text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})=\mathbb{Z}^+$, and a lone morphism $a\to b$ exists if and only if $a\mid b$. Otherwise $\text{Hom}(a,b)=\varnothing$. It can be shown that $\gcd(a,b)$ is a product in $\mathcal{C}$ and $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ is a coproduct in $\mathcal{C}$. My question is:

> Can we recover the identity
>   $$ab=\gcd(a,b)\text{lcm}(a,b)$$
>   from the properties of this category?

My initial thought was to denote a morphism $a\to ak$ by simply $k$ (or a triple $(a,k,ak)$ if we are concerned about disjointness), and then of course composition would just be multiplication: $k:a\to b,\ k':b\to c$, then $kk':a\to c$. Then, by the universal properties of products and coproducts, the diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\gcd(a,b)=d @>{a/d}>> a\\
@V{b/d}VV @VV{\ell/a}V \\
b @>>{\ell/b}> \ell=\text{lcm}(a,b)
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. But of course composition only yields
$$\frac{a}{d}\frac{\ell}{a}=\frac{b}{d}\frac{\ell}{b}.$$
I'm also curious about other identities this category might "know about".

**Edit:** I'm thinking we could just show that 
$$\frac{ab}{\ell}$$
satisfies the universal property for products (or dually, that $ab/d$ is a coproduct) which would imply that $ab/\ell$ is isomorphic to $d$. By definition this implies that $d$ and $ab/\ell$ divide each other, and hence must be equal (hopefully that's correct). Of course, I am open to any other methods involving categorical machinery that I'm not familiar with (limits, pullbacks, etc.) and any other identities that $\mathcal{C}$ may be aware of.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/349858

Comment: See also [Is the gcd the right adjoint of something?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/147900/242)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that $\mathcal C$ does not know what "multiplication" is. The entity $ab$ is entirely meaningless to it.

It is similarly meaningless to say that $\dfrac{ab}\ell$ is the GCD, because as far as $\mathcal C$ is concerned, this object is not connected to $a$, $b$ or $\ell$.

The only thing that $\mathcal C$ can hope to express things about is number-theoretic statements that are solely expressible in terms of divisibility (such as the $\gcd$ and $\rm lcm$).

---

However, a more interesting situation arises when we consider $\mathcal C$ as a (strictly) [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) with multiplication as its "tensor" product $\otimes$.

All of a sudden, we find ourselves in a situation where a meaningful "product" exists. We can even "divide", because given $a \mid c$, we can recover $b := \dfrac c a$ as the coproduct over those $d$ such that $a \otimes d \mid c$. Naturally, then, $a \otimes b = c$.

In standard categorical notation, we can then write the desired identity as: $$a \otimes b = (a + b) \otimes (a \times b)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, I'm having trouble seeing which step in my argument in the edit is incorrect. I understand that saying $ab/\ell=d$ is meaningless in $\mathcal{C}$. But we can say they are isomorphic in $\mathcal{C}$ since they satisfy the same universal property correct?

Comment: @CC0607 Yes, we can say that. But since the operations written down are not performed inside the category, this amounts to nothing but knowing non-categorically (i.e., number-theoretically) that the result holds true.

Comment: That makes prefect sense now. Thanks again.

Comment: do yo perhaps know of a proof that multiplication can't be reconstructed from the divisibility lattice alone?

Comment: @user54748 No, and I didn't manage to come up with one in five minutes, although my intuition says it cannot be done. It might be an interesting follow-up question :).

Comment: I don't believe it can be done either, but you'd need the proof to make the "$\mathcal C$ does not know what "multiplication" is" formal, right?

Comment: @user54748 That would indeed be the most rigorous way to make sure of that. I'll see if I can write up a question about this the coming time.

Comment: @user54748 See [my new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1410202/43351).

Answer (score 3):

In fact, *every* partially ordered set can be viewed as a category in the way you describe; your example is obtained by applying this construction to the poset $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},\mid)$. This process always turns meets into products and joins into coproducts. So your observations are essentially the fact that $\mathrm{gcd}$ is the meet in $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},\mid)$ and $\mathrm{lcm}$ is the join.

As far as I can tell, there's no truly *sensible* way to recover the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ from the poset $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},\mid)$ alone. The problem is that there are certain distinguished chains in $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},\mid),$ namely those of the form $\{n^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\}.$ Speaking vaguely: if you know these, there's a sensible way to recover the multiplicative structure. But the poset $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},\mid)$ alone doesn't "know" these.

Note that, if we identify each element of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ with its multiset of prime factors, then the identity you're interested in becomes:

$$A+B = (A \cup B) + (A \cap B)$$

(in multiset notation), which makes it really obvious why its true!

Comment: This answer reminded me about Qiaochu Yuan mentioning somewhere on MSE that a good way learning of about categorical properties is to look at the analogous property in a poset. So this provides me with a great starting point, I'll give you a (+1) when I have more to share!

Comment: @CC0607, thanks. Yeah honestly I think that order theory should always be taught before category theory, because its a great stepping stone to CT and because posets are important in their own right.