# Prove arithmetic formula for the number of bits in $j=2^k-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

If $k$ is an integer with $0\le k<155$, and $j=2^k-1$, then it holds:
$$k\,=\,5\left(\left\lfloor\frac j{31((j\bmod31)+1)}\right\rfloor\bmod 31\right)-\left\lfloor\frac{12}{(j\bmod31)+3}\right\rfloor+4$$

Why does this equation hold for such a large interval of $k$? How can we prove that?

---

This is a shortened version of more complex formula<sup>#</sup> posted by Hallvard B. Furuseth in a [comp.c post](https://groups.google.com/d/embed/msg/comp.lang.c/NfedEFBFJ0k/9HAqis6IDqcJ) on 2003-11-03, which reportedly works to $k$ of at least $3\cdot10^{10}$.

---

Update (not part of the bountied question): per this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/903600), the same author gave that formula working for $0\le k<2040$:
$$k\,=\,8\left(\left\lfloor\frac j{255((j\bmod255)+1)}\right\rfloor\bmod 255\right)-\left\lfloor\frac{86}{(j\bmod255)+12}\right\rfloor+7$$

---

Try it online [with Python](https://tio.run/##fY7RCoIwFIbv9xQHIthcYtMsEfcqQeHUOXWyzaSnt7mr6KKrn//j/w5nfrtOT9m2HaCVLzFBz9O7ihms0nWg4CkGvVqwehQwyFE6ewLXCSug0WZcHoOFRk419KgWDTS4JyUY4RbjLyUJzliE@2PGKCPER5THLPU4oIzQS7DaXyvN813zEby9FnFxDWKAKaE3hBQ/o7WTg/8FY1ZVisSMcK5KUJQzNBs5OazI1679t9u2Dw) or [with Wolfram Mathematica](https://tio.run/##dY/LDoIwEEX3fMUseRksiBpJt@5M3DfVoBRsS2kCVT4fixAjC2d1JvfOSUbl5sFUbvg9HwbXh4q/WAMCxxe5QtBz8wAJN1brHjqtGNRccROCPeoYlLpVz7zuoORNAQJ8zymJuNIDTk@6IMda65aIyE2QO@4iTBANkOfREVZTjOLoJ0w8Gmwyp5os@4UlTtO5aWn2jDSL9ttoEcdWtcsc52gziddhST4/UYxlGASSZnBueWOIpW@n@t8ZxnkD)! The code computes the upper limits for both formulas.

---

<sup>#</sup> Full formula, for reference (not in the above code or part of the bountied question):
$$\begin{align}k\,=\,&30\left(\left\lfloor\frac j{((j\bmod(2^{30}-1))+1)\,(2^{30}-1)}\right\rfloor\bmod (2^{30}-1)\right)+\\&5\left(\left\lfloor\frac{j\bmod(2^{30}-1)}{31((j\bmod31)+1)}\right\rfloor\bmod 31\right)-\left\lfloor\frac{12}{(j\bmod31)+3}\right\rfloor+4\end{align}$$

Comment: What is your question ??

Comment: @Yves Daoust: that should be clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist integers $m,r$ such that
$$k=5m+r,\qquad 0\le m\le 30,\qquad 0\le r\le 4$$

Since we have
$$j=2^k-1=2^{5m+r}-1=(2^5)^m\cdot 2^r-1\equiv 1^m\cdot 2^r-1\equiv 2^r-1\pmod{31}$$
there exists an integer $a$ such that $2^{5m+r}-1=31a+2^r-1$ which can be written as $$a=2^r(2^{5-r}a+1-2^{5m})$$ This implies that $a$ is divisible by $2^r$, so there exists an integer $b$ such that $j=2^{5m+r}-1=31\cdot 2^rb+2^r-1$.

We have $j\bmod 31=2^r-1$ and $$b\bmod 31=\frac{32^m-1}{31}\bmod 31=(32^{m-1}+32^{m-2}+\cdots +32+1)\bmod 31=m$$
Using these, we get
$$\begin{align}&5\left(\left\lfloor \frac{j}{31((j \bmod 31)+1)}\right\rfloor  \bmod 31\right)-\left\lfloor\frac{12}{(j \bmod 31)+3}\right\rfloor+4
\\\\&=5\left(\left\lfloor \frac{31\cdot 2^rb+2^r-1}{31\cdot 2^r}\right\rfloor  \bmod 31\right)\underbrace{-\left\lfloor\frac{12}{2^r+2}\right\rfloor+4}_{=\ r}
\\\\&=5\left(\left\lfloor b+\frac{2^r-1}{31\cdot 2^r}\right\rfloor  \bmod 31\right)+r
\\\\&=5\left(b  \bmod 31\right)+r
\\\\&=5m+r
\\\\&=k\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the binary representation, and starting from $j=({\underbrace{111\ldots 1}_k})_2$, notice that $j$ can be split (from the left) into groups of *five* $1$'s, with less than five $1$'s remaining at the right end. So, let's write $k=5q+r$ where $0\le r \lt 5$, and look at:

$$j=(\underbrace{11111,11111,11111,\ldots,11111}_q,\underbrace{11\ldots 1}_r)_2$$

(commas added for clarity). Notice also that $(11111)_2=31$ so $j\bmod{31}=(\underbrace{11\ldots 1}_r)_2$ as the rest of the number is obviously divisible by $31$.

### First part of the formula

For the first part of the formula, let's try to calculate $\left\lfloor\frac{j}{31((j\bmod{31})+1)}\right\rfloor$ first. In fact, we want to first divide $j$ by $(j\bmod{31})+1$, which is $(1\underbrace{00\ldots 0}_r)_2$, and then divide by $31$ - but when shall we take the floor function? We will use a helping Lemma below:

**Lemma**: Let $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b,c\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$. Then $\left\lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor}{c}\right\rfloor$.

**Proof**: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6793/700480 . $\blacksquare$

Back to division: to calculate $\left\lfloor\frac{j}{31((j\bmod{31}+1)}\right\rfloor$, we will take the "floor" function twice (as per above Lemma) - first after division by $(j\bmod{31})+1$, which is just the right shift by $r$ places, and then after division by $31$, which already produces the whole number $(\underbrace{1,00001,00001,\ldots,00001}_{q\text{ }1\text{'s}})_2$. (Each group of binary digits $11111$ turns into $00001$.)

Now, this is a sum of numbers of the form $2^{5i}=(2^5)^i=32^i\equiv 1^i=1\pmod{31}$, so $\bmod{31}$ every single one of those $1$'s (at its place value) is equivalent to just $1$, and so the whole number is equivalent to $q$. Now, assuming the total number $k$ of "ones" to start with was $<155$, we have $q<31$ and therefore the whole number $\bmod{31}$ *is* $q$.

Altogether, this means $5\left(\left\lfloor \frac{j}{31((j \bmod 31)+1)}\right\rfloor  \bmod 31\right)=5q$. This explains the first part of the formula.

### Second part of the formula

The second part of the formula: $4-\left\lfloor\frac{12}{(j \bmod 31)+3}\right\rfloor$ is easily explainable, because $j\bmod{31}=(\underbrace{11\ldots 1}_r)_2$ and so it depends only on the remainder $r, 0\le r\lt 5$ rather than on the "whole" $j$. We can do the legwork and check the cases $r=0,1,2,3,4$ and in every case verify that $4-\left\lfloor\frac{12}{(j \bmod 31)+3}\right\rfloor=r$. It just so happens that, when $12$ is divided by numbers $0+3,1+3,3+3,7+3,15+3$, you get $4,3,2,1\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{3}$, the integral part of those numbers are $4,3,2,1,0$, respectively, so subtracting them from $4$ produces the number $r$ we started from.

### Adding it all together

One can now easily verify that $(\text{the first part})+(\text{the second part})=5q+r=k$, as expected.

### The formula with $255$'s

I have not looked in detail, but this second formula looks just like the first one, where $31=(11111)_2$ is replaced by $255=(11111111)_2$. One could expect that $j=2^k-1$ would be broken up into blocks of *eight* $1$'s, that the proof for the first part would go as previously, while, for the second part, the number $86$ was a lucky choice and plays the same role as $12$ played above. (Numbers $0+12, 1+12, 3+12, 7+12, 15+12, 31+12, 63+12, 127+12$, when $86$ is divided by them and then truncated, yield $7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0$ and subtracting them from $7$ recovers the remainder (of $k$ divided by $8$, this time).

### The formula with three terms

Your two-term formula does not work for $k\ge 155$ because, when $k\ge 155$, $q\ge 31$ and instead of $k=5q+r$ you get $5(q\bmod 31)+r$.

To patch that, the third term is added:

- The additional term is based on breaking up the number into groups of $30$ "ones", while the number of those groups should be less than $2^{30}-1$. Thus, it will work for $k<30(2^{30}-1)\approx 3.2212\cdot 10^{10}$.
- The remaining part has up to $30$ "ones", which is less than $155$, so the original formula finishes it off.