# Rational Numbers - LCM and HCF

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading a text book and came across the following approach to find the LCM and HCF of rational numbers/fractions:

- LCM of fractions = LCM of numerators/HCF of denominators
- HCF of fractions = HCF of numerators/LCM of denominators

Can someone please help me understand why the above formula holds true or how the above is logically deduced?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you start with the observation that for integers $a, b, k$ we have $\gcd(ka, kb) = k \gcd(a, b)$ and $\text{lcm}(ka, kb) = k \text{lcm}(a, b)$ and then just extend this to rational $k$. You should get the same result as the above.

Comment: Which textbook is this?

Answer (score 21):

*Notation*: $\text{HCF}$ is denoted below as $\text{gcd}$.

Assume you have two fractions $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}$ reduced to lowest
terms. Let

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
a &=&\underset{i}{\prod } p_{i}^{e_{i}(a)},\qquad b=\underset{i}{\prod } p_{i}^{e_{i}(b)}, \\
c &=&\underset{i}{\prod } p_{i}^{e_{i}(c)},\qquad d=\underset{i}{\prod } p_{i}^{e_{i}(d)}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

be the [prime factorizations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorization.html) of the integers $a,b,c$ and $d$. Then

$$\frac{\underset{i}{\prod }\ p_{i}^{\max \left( e_{i}(a),e_{i}(c)\right) }}{%
\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\min \left( e_{i}(b),e_{i}(d)\right) }}$$

is a fraction which is a common multiple of $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}$. It is
the least one because by the properties of the $\text{lcm}$ and $\gcd $ of
two integers, $\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\max \left( e_{i}(a),e_{i}(c)\right) }$ is the
[least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Finding_least_common_multiples_by_prime_factorization) of the numerators and $\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\min \left(
e_{i}(b),e_{i}(d)\right) }$ is the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_prime_factorizations) of the
denominators. Hence

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{lcm}\left( \frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\right)  &=&\text{lcm}\left( \frac{{\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{e_{i}(a)}}}{\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{e_{i}(b)}},\frac{%
\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{e_{i}(c)}}{\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{e_{i}(d)}}\right)=\frac{\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\max \left( e_{i}(a),e_{i}(c)\right) }}{%
\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\min \left( e_{i}(b),e_{i}(d)\right) }}=\frac{\text{lcm}(a,c)}{\gcd (b,d)}.\quad(1)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Similarly

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\gcd \left( \frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\right) =\gcd \left( \frac{{\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{e_{i}(a)}}}{\prod_{i}p_{i}^{e_{i}(b)}},\frac{%
\prod_{i\ }p_{i}^{e_{i}(c)}}{\prod_{i}p_{i}^{e_{i}(d)}}\right)  =\frac{\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\min \left( e_{i}(a),e_{i}(c)\right) }}{%
\prod_{i}\ p_{i}^{\max \left( e_{i}(b),e_{i}(d)\right) }} =\frac{\gcd (a,c)}{\text{lcm}(b,d)}.\quad(2)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The repeated application of these relations generalizes the result to any
finite number of fractions.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I understand it,

Let $\dfrac 23$, $\dfrac 56$ and $\dfrac 79$ be three fractions. Let $\dfrac AB$ be their LCM. Now all the fractions must divide $\dfrac AB$, that is,$ \dfrac{A}{B} ÷ \dfrac{2}{3},\dfrac{A}{B} ÷ \dfrac{5}{6}$ and $\dfrac{A}{B}  ÷ \dfrac{7}{9} $ all must be natural numbers. Or $\dfrac{A\cdot3}{B\cdot2}, \dfrac{A\cdot6}{B\cdot5}$, and $\dfrac{A\cdot9}{B\cdot7}$ all must be natural numbers. This requires that $A$ must be divisible by $2,5$ and $7$ each and $B$ must be a factor of $3,6$ and $9$ each. In other words, $A$ must be a multiple of $2,5$, and $7$. Now $\dfrac{A}{B}$ must be the lowest possible value, which requires us to choose the highest possible value of $B$ (HCF of denominators) and the lowest possible value of A (LCM of numerators).

Similarly, we can understand how to find the HCF of a given number of fractions.

Answer (score 7):

Below is a proof that works in any GCD domain, using the [universal definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149). These ideas go back to Euclid, who defined the greatest common measure of line segments. Nowadays this can also be viewed in terms of fractional ideals or Krull's $v$-ideals.

**Theorem** $\rm\quad\ \ (a/b,A/B)\: =\: (a,A)/[b,B]\ \ $ if $\rm\ \ (a,b) = 1 = (A,B)$
**Proof**
$\rm\begin{eqnarray} &\rm c &|&\rm a/b,A/B \\
\quad\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm aB,Ab \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (aB,Ab) \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (aB, (A,aB)(b,aB))\ \ &\rm by\quad (x,yz) = (x,y(z,x)),\ \ see\ [2] \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (aB, (A,a) (b,B))\ \ &\rm by\quad  (a,b) = 1 = (A,B) \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (a,A) (b,B)\ \ &\rm by\quad  (A,a)\ |\ a,\ (b,B)\ |\ B \\
\iff&\rm c &|&\rm (a,A)/[b,B]\ \ &\rm by\quad (b,B)\:[b,B] = bB, \ \ see\ [3]
\end{eqnarray}$

Here are links to proofs of the gcd laws used: [law [2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b/20904#20904) and [law [3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44835/for-integers-a-and-b-ab-textlcma-b-cdot-texthcfa-b/44843#44843).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this result holds true under the assumption that the fractions are in their simplest forms... Otherwise it might not hold.
eg. 8/12, 4/9 LCM is in fact 4/3. But using your method we get 8/3.