# Period of N systems each with a period p

Tags: periodic-functions

Lets say you have a set of functions `F` so that function `f1` has a period `p1` and so on. How would I go about to find the time `t` such that all the functions in `F` are at the start of a new period at `t`?

Example:

```
F = {sin(x), sin(2x), sin(0.5x)}
f1 intersects (as multiples of pi): [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
f2 intersects (as multiples of pi): [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4]
f3 intersects (as multiples of pi): [0, 2, 4]

The only common intersects are 0 and 4 so the period is 4
```

My initial thought was to take the LCM of the periods, however if the period is a real value I don't really know how to find the LCM.

Any suggestion for how to solve this without produce a set of all the indices that correspond to the start of a period and grabbing the intersection?

Comment: The lcm of rational numbers still exists. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44836/rational-numbers-lcm-and-hcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the periods line up if and only if they are rational multiples of one another. If this condition is satisfied, for example if the periods are $\alpha q_1,\dots,\alpha q_n$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q_1,\dots,q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, then they all line up at time $$ \alpha \cdot\text{lcm}(q_1,\dots,q_n)$$ where the LCM of rational numbers are taken as in the comment above.