# Largest possible common difference of an arithmetic progression given its three terms (not necessarily adjacent)

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

How can I find the largest possible common difference of an arithmetic progression given that its three terms (not necessarily adjacent) are $0.37$, $9$ and $\frac{71}{7}$?

Comment: Can OP check again the 3 terms? The common difference seems to be absurdly small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common difference must divide the difference of any two terms of an AP. So it must divide $9-0.37=863/100$ and $71/7-9=8/7$. You want the largest common difference, i.e. the HCF of $8.63$ and $8/7$. Now use the following link: [Rational Numbers - LCM and HCF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44836/rational-numbers-lcm-and-hcf).

Comment: $9 - 0.37 = 863/100$ but by the method you proposed the GCD is pretty small.

Comment: @Yuki.F Thanks for spotting the error. The difference is indeed small. Did I miss a larger solution?

Comment: The answer sheet says $\frac{1}{700}$, which is the HCF of $8.63$ and $\frac{8}{7}$.

Comment: @Dambacha Cool, my answer is correct then.

Comment: HCF and LCM of fractions is a concept I've never heard before, though. I'll try and look for a video explanation as I didn't quite understand those given in the linked thread. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Dambacha You can get in touch with me using the comment option if you have trouble understanding.

Comment: Actually I understood the concept thanks to the third solution in the thread you linked by user103816, which was the best and the simplest explanation. Not sure why it isn't the top voted one!