# Relating $\operatorname{lcm}$ and $\gcd$ using inverses or fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I would appreciate help to show this equality is valid:  $\operatorname{lcm} (u, v) = \gcd (u^{- 1}, v^{- 1})^{- 1}$, where $u, v$ are elements of a field of fractions.

In the text it is stated that lcm is: there is an element $m$ in K for which $u| x$ and $v| x$ is equivalent to $m| x$

It goes on to say sending $t$ to $t^{- 1}$ in K reverses divisibility. So the proof of the existence of lcm's reduces to the proof of the existence of gcd's.

Then from the relation I am asking about above, one obtains $\operatorname{lcm} (u,v)\gcd (u,v) = uv$

I know independently how to show $\operatorname{lcm} (u,v)\gcd (u,v) = uv$. But the text I am looking at uses the first to show the second.

Thanks.

Comment: In what context are you taking the gcd of $u^{-1}$ and $v^{-1}$? If $u$ is invertible, then it is a unit, so it divides everything and only units divide it, same for $v$, so that $\gcd(u^{-1},v^{-1})$ would necessarily be $1$. So you must mean something other than the standard definition of $\gcd$. What do you mean?

Comment: In addition to @ArturoMagidin's comment, also 1 is a multiple of $u$ and $v$ if they are invertible. So the equation does make sense but for trivial reasons.

Comment: However, you may mean "gcd" in terms of a largest "common measure", as per Euclid. That is, if $u$ and $v$ are integers, then you are looking for the largest rational of the form $\frac{1}{a}$ such that $\frac{1}{u}$ and $\frac{1}{v}$ are integer multiples of $\frac{1}{a}$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin You're right, I should have said u,v are elements of a field of fractions, K. Will fix that. To be honest, I don't know if that will answer what you pose.

Comment: My understanding is that $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ can be uniquely extended from a ring to its field of fractions with their multiplicative properties (e.g. $\gcd(ac,bc)=c\gcd(a,b)$). But to use the first equation to go to the second seems strangely backwards.

Comment: @Andrew: If you define $\gcd(x,y)$ as: a number $d$ such that $d|x$, $d|y$, and for every $c$, if $c|x$ and $c|y$ then $c|d$, then it doesn't help. It's still the case that if either $x$ or $y$ are invertible, then $\gcd(x,y) = 1$. So perhaps you are looking for an extension along the lines of what anon suggests, or as I mentioned above. But it cannot be the "usual" definition of $\gcd$ in terms of divisibility, because then you just get $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)=\gcd(a,b)=1$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are both units.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin REgarding your second comment - I think that's it. I came across this in Samuel's "Algebraic Theory of Numbers" page 14.

Comment: @Andrew: Perhaps you can add the relevant definitions, then?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sure

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, if there's more than one unit in the ring, can we even define $\gcd$ unambiguously? :)

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: gcd is always defined only up to a unit. Only in special circumstances can we select a distinguished one (e.g., the integers, where we pick "the positive one", or polynomial rings over fields, where we pick "the monic one").

Comment: @Andrew: The important definition is that of gcd when you are talking about elements that are *invertible*, not that of lcm. If, as I suspect, you are essentially looking for the largest common measure, then the asserted equality is true, but the problem is *whether* that is what is being sought.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I am over my head. Along with the definition of lcm I added above, the relation (including the hint) I am asking about was given. So I was trying to do the mechanics.

Comment: @Andrew: Since you seem to think you are over your head, perhaps you can **quote** what is given, instead of trying to paraphrase something you are not sure you understand correctly? For instance, your "definition" mentions $K$, but $K$ appears *ex nihilo*, with no context and no meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a domain $D$, and are looking at the field of fractions as a $D$-module. You are now looking for multiples and divisors but only $D$-multiples. That is, letting $D$ be the domain and $F$ be the field of fractions, we define:

> Let $a,b\in F$. We say $x\in F$ is a *least common multiple of $a$ and $b$* if and only if:
>
> 1. There exist $r,s\in D$ such that $ra=x$ and $sb=x$; and
> 2. If $y\in F$ is such that there exist $u,v\in D$ with $ua=y$ and $vb=y$, then there exists $t\in D$ such that $xt=y$.

**Note well:** we are only talking about "$D$-multiples". If we take $D=\mathbb{Z}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$, this would be the equivalent of saying that $a$ and $b$ "measure" $x$, and that $x$ measures any number that is measured by both $a$ and $b$ (in the sense of Euclid).

Similarly,

> Let $a,b\in F$. We say that $d\in F$ is a *greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$* if and only if:
>
> 1. There exist $r,s\in D$ such that $rd=a$ and $sd=b$; and
> 2. If $c\in F$ is such that there exist $u,v\in D$ with $uc=a$ and $vc=b$, then there exists $t\in D$ such that $tc=d$.

**Note again:** We are talking about "$D$-divisors" only. Again, in the language of Euclid, this means that $d$ "measures" both $a$ and $b$, and that any common measure of $a$ and $b$ "measures" $d$.

Now, suppose that $d$ is a gcd for $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. We are trying to show that $d^{-1}$ is a least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

Since there exist $r,s\in D$ with $rd = a^{-1}$ and $sd=b^{-1}$, we see that $ra=d^{-1}$ and $sb=d^{-1}$, so $d^{-1}$ is a common $D$-multiple of $a$ and $b$. Now suppose that $c$ is a common $D$-multiple of $a$ and $b$. Then there exist $x,y\in D$ such that $ax=c$ and $by=c$. Therefore $c^{-1}x = a^{-1}$ and $c^{-1}y=b^{-1}$, so $c^{-1}$ is a common $D$-divisor of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. Since $d$ is a gcd for $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, it follows that there exists $z\in D$ such that $zc^{-1}=d$, and therefore $zd^{-1}=c$. Thus, $c$ is a $D$-multiple of $d^{-1}$.

This proves that $d^{-1}$ is a least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, under these definitions. That is, we have shown that
$$\mathrm{lcm}(a,b) = \gcd(a^{-1},b^{-1})^{-1}$$
as desired.

**Added.** More generally, as noted by [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) in this [old sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?messageID=6893421&tstart=0), we have:

**Theorem.** Let $a,b,c,d\in D$. If $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$, then
$$\gcd\left(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\right) = \frac{\gcd(a,c)}{\mathrm{lcm}(b,d)}.$$

In the case at hand, assuming $u$ and $v$ are in $D$, we have $a=1$, $c=1$, $b=u$, $d=v$, so we obtain
$$\gcd\left(\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{v}\right) = \frac{\gcd(1,1)}{\mathrm{lcm}(u,v)}$$
which gives the result as well.

Comment: @ArturoMagidinThanks very much.

Comment: @Andrew Yes. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Below is a proof that works in any GCD domain, using the [universal definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b/20904#20904). These ideas go back to Euclid, who defined the greatest common measure of line segments. Nowadays this can be viewed more generally in terms of fractional ideals or Krull's $v$-ideals.

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ \  \left(\dfrac{a}b,\,\dfrac{A}B\right)\: =\: \dfrac{(a,A)}{[b,B]}\ \ $ if $\rm\ \ (a,b) = 1 = (A,B),\ \ $ where $\rm\ \ \begin{eqnarray} (a,b) &:=&\rm\ gcd\rm(a,b)\\\ \rm [a,b]\, &:=&\rm\ lcm(a,b)\end{eqnarray}$

**Proof**
$\rm\begin{eqnarray} &\rm\quad c &|&\rm a/b,\,A/B \\
\quad\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm\ aB,\,Ab \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (aB,\,\color{#C00}A\color{#0A0}b) \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (aB,\, (\color{#C00}A,aB)\,(\color{#0A0}b,aB))\ \ &\rm by\quad (x,\color{#C00}y\color{#0A0}z) = (x,\,(\color{#C00}y,x)\,(\color{#0A0}z,x)),\ \ see\ [1] \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (aB,\, (A,a)\, (b,B))\ \ &\rm by\quad  (a,b) = 1 = (A,B) \\
\iff&\rm Bbc &|&\rm (a,A)\,(b,B)\ \ &\rm by\quad  (A,a)\ |\ a,\ (b,B)\ |\ B \\
\iff&\rm\quad c &|&\rm (a,A)/[b,B]\ \ &\rm by\quad (b,B)\:[b,B] = bB, \ \ see\ [2]
\end{eqnarray}$

Here are said links to proofs of the gcd laws used: [law [1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b/20904#20904) and [law [2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44835/for-integers-a-and-b-ab-textlcma-b-cdot-texthcfa-b/44843#44843).

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3940597/242) for the $k$-ary inductive extension of the above gcd formula.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$Here is the way I usually show $ab = \lcm(a,b)\gcd(a,b)$. Inequality $(2)$ uses that we are working in an integral domain. Without something like that, the argument seems circular.

First notice that $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} = a(\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}) = b(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)})$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$.  By the minimality of the $\lcm$, $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} \ge \lcm(a,b)$.
That is
$$
ab \ge \lcm(a,b)\gcd(a,b)\tag{1}
$$
By division, we can write $ab = q\lcm(a,b) + r$ where $0 \le r < \lcm(a,b)$.
Because $ab$ and $\lcm(a,b)$ are common multiples of $a$ and $b$, so is $r$.  By the minimality of the $\lcm$, $r = 0$.  Therefore, $\lcm(a,b)$ divides $ab$.  Notice that $\frac{ab}{\lcm(a,b)} = \frac{a}{\lcm(a,b)/b} = \frac{b}{\lcm(a,b)/a}$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.  By the maximality of the $\gcd$, $\frac{ab}{lcm(a,b)} \le \gcd(a,b)$.  That is
$$
ab \le \lcm(a,b)\gcd(a,b)\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get $ab = \lcm(a,b)\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: @RobjohnThanks for your answer. As I mentioned, I can do this. What I was trying to see is the relation I am asking about. If I am not mistaken, going from what you show is probably doable. But the text goes the other way.

Comment: @andrew: so the question was how to extend gcd and lcm to rationals.  I apologize for missing that.

Comment: @RobjohnNo need - I appreciate anything anyone does for others here.