# Reducing multivariate rational fractions to lowest terms

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, divisibility, factoring, principal-ideal-domains

I wish to simplify multivariate rational fractions to a canonical form.

Thanks to some very helpful mathematically inclined people who verified that
my understanding of Wikipedia was correct, I'm now confident that:

1. GCD of multivariate polynomials over a UFD is unique up to the
   multiplication by a unit of the UFD.
2. Multivariate rational fractions over a UFD have a simplified form that is
   unique up to the multiplication of the numerator and denominator by a unit of
   the UFD. By requiring that the denominator is a primitive polynomial, it can
   be made unique up to the multiplication of the numerator and denominator by
   -1. By also fixing the monomial order and fixing the sign of a leading
   monomial, it can be made completely unique.
3. While multivariate polynomial division over a UFD is not unique in general,
   it's unique if there's no remainder.

As far as I can see, it follows that the unique simplified form for
multivariate rational fractions can be acquired the same way as for univariate
rational fractions: By dividing the numerator and denominator by their GCD. (And fiddling with the result a bit)

The question then becomes: How to calculate multivariate polynomial GCD, and
division when there's no remainder? (In a conceptually simple way, without
having to resort to Gröbner bases)

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Proof_that_GCD_exists_for_multivariate_polynomials):

> A polynomial in n variables may be considered as a univariate
>   polynomial over the ring of polynomials in (n − 1) variables. Thus a
>   recursion on the number of variables shows that if GCDs exists and may
>   be computed in R, then they exist and may be computed in every
>   multivariate polynomial ring over R. In particular, if R is either the
>   ring of the integers or a field, then GCDs exist in R[x1,...,xn], and
>   what precedes provides an algorithm to compute them.

Does this mean that the multivariate polynomial GCD can be calculated with
Euclid's algorithm? Euclid's algorithm uses Euclidean division; Does this mean
you can use it with multivariate polynomials by thinking of them as univariate
polynomials over polynomials with (n - 1) variables? Does this give the
correct answer in general when used in Euclid's algorithm and also in cases
when there's no remainder?

As far as I can see, you'll end up with rational fractions as the coefficients
when you do the division of the leading coefficients in Euclidean division
(and recurse to the next level of polynomials to simplify the fraction), but
at the end you can multiply the numerator and denominator at each level by the
LCM of the denominators of the terms' coefficients so that you'll be left with
a rational fraction only at the outermost level. Is there something wrong with
this? Is there a simpler way to do this?

And finally: Although the approach of recursion on the number of variables is
conceptually simple (assuming it works in general), dealing with levels upon
levels of rational fractions isn't going to be fun. Does there exist an
algorithm that can be used to do the division directly with multivariate
polynomials, that gives the correct answer in general? (ie. the remainders it
gives work for Euclid's algorithm and it gives the correct answer when there's
no remainder)

One way I've considered is using the univariate algorithm with lexicographical
monomial ordering and allowing negative exponents during the algorithm, then
at the end multiplying the numerator and denominator by such a monomial that
all the exponents become non-negative. Could this work?

*Explicit counter-examples would be very much appreciated if there's a mistake somewhere; As someone else once so eloquently [put it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151081/gcd-of-rationals), "I'm not a mathematician, so please type slowly :-)"*