# How to determine whether a polynomial is primitive in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am given a polynomial $$ f = 2x^{2} + 4x + 6$$

and I have to determine in which of the rings, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, or $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$, $f$ is a primitive polynomial, and I have to compute the content $C(f)$ in each case.

For $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, I was able to calculate $C(f)$ by using the Euclidean algorithm on the coefficients $2,4,6$, and found it to be $2$. Since $2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, I determined that $f$ is NOT primitive there.

For $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$, I reduced all the coefficients $\mod 5$ and then found $C(f)$ to be equal to $1$, again, via the Euclidean algorithm. Since $1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, I determined that $f$ is primitive there.

My question is what to do in the case of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Of course, all integers are also rationals, but can I use the same Euclidean algorithm to find the same $C(f)$, and then determine that because $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$ that $f$ is primitive in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$? Or is there a different way to calculate the $\gcd$ of rational numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151081

Comment: Hint: In a field every nonzero element is a unit,  so every nonzero polynomial has a unit coefficient, and units have only unit divisors, so ...

Comment: In a field every nonzero element is  unit: this means that every nonzero polynomial is primitive.

Comment: @Crostul Why spoil the hint?

Comment: @SahibaArora so using that method, the $\gcd$ of $2$, $4$, and $6$ will be the same regardless of whether I consider them to be rationals or integers?

Comment: @BillDubuque I still need to calculate the content in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ because I was asked to, regardless of how I determined whether the polynomial is primitive. Am I correct then that the content will be the same in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as it is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, since the $\gcd$ of the coefficients will be the same regardless of whether I treat them as rationals or integers?

Comment: @ALannister Absolutely.

Comment: @ALannister If some gcd argument is a unit then the gcd divides that unit so it must also be a unit. Normally unit gcds are normalized to be $1$ (gcds are unique only up to associates, i.e. unit multiples).