# Proof involving lcm and biconditional statement.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, least-common-multiple

Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $a = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ if and only if $b\mid a$

Unsure of how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$ By definition $\lcm(a,b)=bk$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. So if $bk=a$ then $b\mid a$ by definition.

Conversely, $b\mid a$ implies $\lcm(a,b)\le a$ and $a\mid a$ implies $\lcm(a,b)\ge a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ b\mid a \iff a,b\mid a \iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid a\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b) = a$

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145069),
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)=ab
$$
Thus, we have that
$$
\gcd(a,b)=b
$$
This means that $b$ is a divisor of $a$; i.e. $b\mid a$.

Comment: I see that, nowadays, Bezout is deleted. This is much healthier!

Comment: @BillDubuque: ah, but I do use properties of [Euclidean Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) in the cited answer; very similar to your [Bezout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).