# Relationship between GCD and LCM

Tags: number-theory

Could someone help me prove that
$$\frac{1}{{\gcd \left( {\frac{1}{{{a_1}}}, \ldots ,\frac{1}{{{a_n}}}} \right)}} = \operatorname{lcm} \left( {{a_1}, \ldots ,{a_n}} \right) $$
without using that $\gcd \left( {a,b} \right)\operatorname{lcm} \left( {a,b} \right) = ab$.

Comment: How are gcds and lcms defined for nonintegers? And what *can* be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in a closely related question on [gcd & lcm of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145054/242)

$\begin{align} {\rm lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mid x
\iff\  \ &a_1,\ldots a_n\mid x\\
\iff\ \ &\ 1\mid x/a_1,\ldots, x/a_n\\
\iff\ \ &\ 1\mid \gcd(x/a_1,\ldots, x/a_n)\\
\iff\ \ &\ 1\mid x\,\gcd(1/a_1,\ldots, 1/a_n) =: x\,g\\
\iff\ \ &\!\!\!\!1/g\mid x
\end{align}$