# The form of inverse ideals in a GCD-domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

In my lecture I encountered the following reasoning:

> Let $R$ be a GCD-domain and let $I$ be an invertible ideal in $R$. Since $I$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module we can write $I=(a_1/b_1,...,a_n/b_n)R$, where $a_i, b_i$ are elements in $R$. (Recall that by hypothesis $R$ is also an LCM-domain.) Let $c$ be the least common multiple of the $b_i$'s, $d$ be the greatest common divisor of the $a_i$'s. We see that $I^{-1}=(c/d)R$.

I do not understand why $I^{-1}=(c/d)R$ should hold. I understand the trivial direction $I^{-1} \supseteq (c/d)R$, but I do not get why $I^{-1} \subseteq (c/d)R$ should be true. Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remarked in a comment on the same [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4149087/242) last week, this is an immediate consequence of  $\,\rm\color{#c00}U$ = [universal gcd property for fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3940597/242) over a gcd domain, viz.

$$\begin{align}
&\!a/b \in (a_1/b_1,\ldots a_n/b_n)^{-1}\\[.2em]
\iff\ & b/a\mid a_1/b_1,\ldots,a_n/b_n\\[.2em]
\smash[t]{\overset{\rm\color{#c00}U}\iff}\ \ \, & b/a\mid d/c,\ \  d= \gcd\{a_i\}, c={\rm lcm}\{b_i\} \\[.2em]
\iff\ &\!a/b \in (c/d)
\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: Note that this proves *both* directions simultaneously.