# Proof writing: Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $m=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$. Prove that $dm=|ab|$.

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $m=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$. Prove that $dm=|ab|$.

Can I just show that since $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=|ab|$ iff $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $dm=(1)|ab|=|ab|$? Or is there a more simple proof to this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533352/proof-displaystyle-textlcmx-y-fracx-cdot-y-textgcdx-y?rq=1

Comment: I don't see you  infer from the case ‘$a, b$ coprime to the general case.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
a&=& p_1^{ \alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_i^{\alpha_i} \\
b&=& p_1^{ \beta_1} p_2^{\beta_2} \cdots p_i^{\beta_i} \\
hcf(a,b) &=& p_1^{\min(\alpha_1, \beta_1)} p_2^{\min(\alpha_2 ,\beta_2)} \cdots p_i^{\min(\alpha_i ,\beta_i)} \\
lcm(a,b) &=& p_1^{\max(\alpha_1, \beta_1)} p_2^{\max(\alpha_2, \beta_2)} \cdots p_i^{\max(\alpha_i ,\beta_i)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use $\min(\alpha ,\beta)+\max(\alpha ,\beta)=\alpha +\beta$.

Comment: How elegant! :)