# Prove $o(gcd(g,h))=lcm(o(g),o(h))$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G,H$ groups and $g\in G, h\in H$.
>   Prove that in $G \times H$: $$o(\gcd(g,h))=\mathrm{lcm}(o(g),o(h))$$ lcm= Least Common Multiple

How should I approach this? do $G \times H$ must be a finite group?

Comment: What is $\gcd(g,h)$? Do you mean $o(g,h)$ in $G\times H$?

Comment: $ o(\gcd (g, h))$ makes no sense. Shouldn't it be $ o(g, h) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ (1,1) = (g,h)^n = (g^n,h^n)\iff o(g),o(h)\mid n\color{#c00}\iff {\rm lcm}(o(g),o(h))\mid n$

The $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ arrow is the fundamental [universal property of LCM:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242) $\ a,b\mid n\color{#c00}\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid n$