# Find the smallest integer $a > 2$ such that $2|a, 3|a + 1, 4|a + 2, 5|a + 3, 6|a + 4$

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest integer $a > 2$ such that
$2|a, 3|a + 1, 4|a + 2, 5|a + 3, 6|a + 4$

The question is from David Burton's book on Number Theory. The solution which I have found is like this:

Since $2|a$ is equivalent to $4|a + 2$ and $6|a + 4$ is equivalent to $3|a + 1$, so the given
problem reduces in finding the smallest integer $a > 2$ such that $3|a + 1, 4|a + 2, 5|a + 3$. Thus, we have to find the
least value of $a > 2$ such that $a \equiv 2 \mod 4$, $a \equiv 2 \mod 5$ and $a \equiv 2 \mod 6$. Since 4 and 6 are not
co-prime, so Chinese Remainder Theorem is not applicable. However, we observe that $a = 62$ serves as a solution. This is
the smallest solution because $a \equiv 2 \mod 6$ implies that if $2 < a < 62$, then possible values for $a$ are 8, 14,
20, 26, 32, 38, 44, 50 and 56. But $8 \not \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $14 \not \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $20 \not \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $26
\not \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $32 \not \equiv 2 \mod 4$, $38 \not \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $44 \not \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $50 \not \equiv 2
\mod 5$, and $56 \not \equiv 2 \mod 5$. Thus, the desired least value of $a$ is 62.

Comment: As to how @barakmanos found it, hint: think about the $LCM(2,3,4,5,6)$

Comment: It holds for $a=60n+2$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Would you please give some detail about how you knew that the solution is $a = 60n + 2$?

Comment: Not sure why this was voted to be close.  But $2|a$ is equivalent to $4|a+2$????  What if a =, say, 16?  $6|a+4$ equivalent to $3|a+1$?  What if $a$ is even, say $a = 5$  $3|5+1$ but $6|5+4$.  Not equivalent at all.

Comment: But they are conditional.  If $4|a+2$ then $2|a+2$ and $2|a$ (but the reverse direction does not work).  If $6|a+4$ then $3|a+4$ so $3|a+1$ (but the reverse direction does not work).... Actually $6|a+4 \implies$ both $3|a+1$ and $2|a$.

Answer (score 2):

$\ \begin{align}{\bf Hint}\qquad\quad &a\equiv 2\! \pmod{ 2,3,4,5,6}\\[.1em] 
\iff\ &2,3,4,5,6\mid a\!-\!2\\[.1em] 
\iff\ &60\mid a\!-\!2, \ \ {\rm by} \ \ 60 = {\rm lcm}(2,3,4,5,6)\\[.1em] 
\iff\ &a\equiv2\! \pmod{60}\end{align}$

Comment: Which result have you used?

Comment: @Khalid The [universal property](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242) of lcm, i.e. $ a,b,c\ldots \mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b,c\ldots )\mid n\ \ $

Comment: @Khalid I added a link to a proof of the LCM universal property.

Comment: One more question Mr Bill Dubuque Please. The figure 2 in $a \equiv 2$ comes where from?

Comment: @Khalid Note each divisibility has form $\ c\mid a+c-2,\ $ e.g. $\ 5\mid a+3 = a+5-2.\,$ Therefore $$ {\rm mod}\,\ c\!:\,\  0\equiv a+c-2\equiv a-2\ \Rightarrow\ a\equiv 2\qquad\!$$