# Prove that for the additive group (Z, +) of integers every subgroup is of the form kZ.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that for the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ of integers every subgroup is of the form $k\mathbb{Z}$.

Here is the proof I [wrote](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abb5j2f8ls2oh8l/PracFinal03.pdf?dl=0), and I knew it was off, so I sent it to my professor for some help.  His reply:  "Sorry, but you missed the point. You needed to show that any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k$. Keep on trying."
Which is less than helpful.  This is a problem off a practice final.

Can someone give me a hint to get me started?

edit:  here's my new attempt.  [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d19c8wzg2l0nppz/PracFinal03a.pdf?dl=0)   Is this enough?  Or is more needed?

Comment: You did miss the point.  Your argument (correctly) shows that the set $k\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup but that's not what you were asked.  You were asked to prove that EVERY subgroup has that form.

Comment: You proved that $k\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup. What you are supposed to prove is that if you are handed a subgroup $H$ it is really just one of the  $k\mathbb{Z}$'s. Hint: what is the smallest nonzero element in $k\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You start proving that $kZ $ is a subgroup. But you can't do that if uou're yo answer the question. You need to start with the addumptio that $U $ is a subgroup of $(Z,+)$ and shiw that $U=kZ$ for some $k $.

Comment: Hint: see the Lemma in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242)

Comment: Showing that $k\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup is quite different from show that any $H\leq \Bbb Z$ has the form $k\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you proved is that $k\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup for any $k$. But to prove the statement given to you, your proof should begin: "Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$" and conclude with "Therefore $H = k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$."

If $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, try looking at the smallest (in absolute value) element of $H$.

Comment: Ah... you said absolute value.  Others just said "what's the smallest value" and for integers, there isn't one, there's always a smaller integer.  But if you say absolute value... now you can say 1.  Maybe I can start with that.

Comment: The new attempt at the link is good proof! It would be good to include a reference to where that lemma is coming from, for completeness.