# Least common denominator of fractions: name, minimality, generalizations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, terminology

Suppose we're given a $k$-long list of rational numbers:

$$q : \{0,\ldots,k-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}.$$

Then there's a least $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $nq_i$ is an integer for all $i$.

> **Question.** What is this integer $n$ called, and does it have any generalizations/related concepts in ring theory?

For what it's worth, I think $n$ can be computed as follows. Given a rational number $q$, lets define that the *denominator* of $q$ is the least $b \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $q=a/b$ for some integer $a$. This defines a function $$\mathrm{den}:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{>0}.$$ If I'm not mistaken, $n$ can be computed as $$\mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}_{i=0}^{k-1} \mathrm{den}(q_i).$$

Here's a "real" world example of how this shows up. Suppose we have a box with three kinds of chocolate; dark, white, and milk. We're given that if we reach into this box to pull out a random chocolate, there's $1/3$ probability of getting dark, $1/4$ probability of getting white, and hence $5/12$ probability of getting milk. The question is; what's the minimum number of chocolates in this box? The answer can be found by computing $n$ for the aforementioned rational numbers; this gives $12$, so that's the minimum number of chocolates that could be in the box.

Comment: I don't think it has a name, but your formula to find it looks like it ought to be correct.

Comment: [LCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator)

Comment: @DanielFischer, oh, haha. That makes so much sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer As trivial as it is, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n\,$ is the *least common denominator* of the rationals $\,q_i.\,$ As you remarked, it is the lcm of the denominators when the fractions are written in least terms, since

$$ n\, a_i/b_i\in\Bbb Z\iff b_i\mid n a_i\overset{(a_i,b_i)\,=\,1}\iff\, b_i\mid n\!\overset{\rm\color{#c00}U\!\!}\iff {\rm lcm}\{b_i\}\mid n$$

where we employed  $\rm\color{#c00}U$ = [lcm Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242).

Note  $\, \dfrac{a_i}{b_i} = \dfrac{c_i}n$ with $\,n\,$ least $\Rightarrow \gcd(n,c_1,\cdots, c_k)=1,\,$ else $\,1<p\mid n,c_i\,$ so we can cancel $p$ from all $\,c_i/n\,$ to get $\,a_i/b_i= (c_i/p)/(n/p),\,$ so $\,n/p\,$ is a smaller common denom, contra $\,n\,$ least such.

For some generalizations and related concepts see posts on [denominator ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denominator+ideal)
and [order ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+order+ideal)

One common application of denominator ideals is to irrationality proofs. Using Dedekind's notion of *conductor* (universal denominator) ideal allows one to unify and generalize most of the common descent-based irrationality proofs, e.g. see the appended post [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39769/242) As I show there, they generalize to a one-line proof that PIDs are integrally closed (monic case of Rational Root Test). More generally, the conductor ideal plays a key role when studying rings of algebraic integers.