# The order of $(g,h)$ equals the least common multiple of ord(g) and ord(h)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups and let $g∈G$ and $h∈H$ be two elements of  finite orders. Is the order of $(g,h)$ equals the least common multiple of $\operatorname{ord}(g)$ and $\operatorname{ord}(h)$? That is $$\operatorname{ord}(g,h)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(g),\operatorname{ord}(h))$$It is my conjecture, and I am not sure if it is correct or not. If it's true, how can I formally prove it?

Comment: show that the least common multiple as an exponent indeed gives the neutral element. Then prove that this must be the smallest such positive integer (for example, by assuming that a smaller exponent achieving this would result in a contradiction).

Comment: It is perfectly correct, and more or less obvious from the definition of the order of an element.

Comment: @Student Wondering if it more easy to approach this problem using additive version instead of multiplicative version of group?  I mean, using "+" instead of "*"?

Comment: That won't make it easier. It is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(g,h)^n\! = (g^n,h^n) = (1,1)\!\iff\! g^n=1=h^n\! \iff o(g),o(h)\mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(o(g),o(h)\mid n,\, $ where the final step uses the [lcm universal property:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242) $\ a,b\mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid n$