# proving a lemma for order of an element

Tags: multiplicative-order

Given an integer *a* and a positive integer n with gcd(a,n) = 1, the multiplicative order of a modulo n is the smallest positive integer k with
$a^k \equiv 1 (mod\ n)$

There exist a lemma to this saying that

$ [a]^r$ for $0 <= r <= k-1$ has order k if and only if gcd$(r,k)=1$

I want to prove this by contradiction but i might not be doing the setup correctly.

$ [a]^r$ for $0 <= r <= k-1$ has a order less than k if and only if gcd$(r,k) !=1$

Comment: Tip: use \le and \ge to obtain $\le$ and $\ge$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\ (a^{\large r})^{\large x}\!=1 \!\iff\! k\mid rx\!\iff\! k\mid rx,kx\!\iff\! k\mid (rx,kx)\!=\! (r,k)x\!\iff\! k/(r,k)\mid x\ $

The first $\iff$[follows by](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)  $\,k = {\rm\ ord}\, a,\,$ and the third  by the $\rm gcd$ [universal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) and [distributive law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242)

Since $\,\ell = {\rm ord}\,a^{\large r}\,$ is the *least* such $\,x,\,$ clearly  $\ \ell = k/(r,k),\ $ so  $\ \ell = k\iff (r,k)= 1$

**Remark** $\ $ Alternatively, dually, instead of $\rm gcd$ we can use $\rm lcm$ and its [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242), i.e.

$\quad\ \ (a^{\large r})^{\large x} = 1\iff k\mid rx\iff r,k\mid rx\iff {\rm lcm}(r,k)\mid rx\iff {\rm lcm}(r,k)/r\mid x$

They agree since $\ {\rm lcm}(r,k)/r = k/\gcd(r,k)\,$ by $\ {\rm lcm}(r,k)\gcd(r,k) = rk,\,$ by [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318902/242)