# Prove that if LCMs are equal, then the numbers are equal too.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

For $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, how do I prove:

> $$lcm(a,a+5)=lcm(b,b+5) \implies a=b$$

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a,a+5) \mid 5\,$.

Comment: Should state that $a$ and $b$ are *positive* (or nonnegative) integers.  Otherwise, there are silly counterexamples like $\text{lcm}(-1,4)=\text{lcm}(-4,1)$.

Comment: So we have $\frac{a(a+5)}{5k} = \frac{b(b+5)}{5m}$. Multiplying it doesn't seem to give anything. What now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed $a$ and $b$ were positive integers.

We have $\mathrm{lcm}(a,a+5) = \frac {a(a+5)}{\gcd(a,a+5)}$, so that the given equality implies
$$\frac {a(a+5)}{\gcd(a,a+5)} = \frac {b(b+5)}{\gcd(b,b+5)}.$$
But $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x,y+kx)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $\gcd(a,a+5) = \gcd(a,5)$ and $\gcd(b,b+5) = \gcd(b,5)$.

Now if $a$ and $b$ are not multiples of $5$ we have $\gcd(a,5) = 1$ and $\gcd(b,5) = 1$ then
$$\frac {a(a+5)}{\gcd(a,a+5)} = \frac {b(b+5)}{\gcd(b,b+5)} \implies \frac{a*(a+5)}{1} = \frac{b*(b+5)}{1} \implies a = b.$$

If both $a$ and $b$ are multiple of $5$ then $\gcd(a,5) = \gcd(b,5) = 5$ so that 
$$\frac {a(a+5)}{\gcd(a,a+5)} = \frac {b(b+5)}{\gcd(b,b+5)} \implies a(a+5) = b(b+5).$$From here we can conclude that $a=b$ by completing the square both sides and using the fact that a,b are positive.

Edit :

If $a$ is a multiple of $5$ and not $b$ we have $$a(a+5)=5b(b+5).$$ But $a=5a′$, then the last equality becomes $$5a′(a′+1)=b(b+5).$$ The left side is a multiple of $5$ but not the right side so this case never happens (same reasoning for the case $b$ multiple of $5$ and not $a$).

Comment: "Now if a and b are not multiples of 5 we have gcd(a,5)=5a and gcd(b,5)=5b". By gcd, I assume you mean greatest common divisor? Because 5a doesn't divide a, except when a=0.

Comment: In the case where $a$,$b$ are not divisible by $5$ you write $\gcd(a,5) = 5a$.  No, that's the LCM; the GCD is $1$.

Comment: Oops my bad! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I already did that and a couple of other modifications, provided they get accepted. You keep the reputation bud, I'm too lazy to write such amount of LaTex at the middle of the night.

Comment: Well thanks then. :)

Comment: And why can't one be a multiple of $5$ and the other not?

Comment: If $a$ is a multiple of $5$ and not $b$ we have $a(a+5) = 5b(b+5)$. But $a = 5a'$, then the last equality becomes $5a'(a'+1) = b(b+5)$. The left side is a multiple of $5$ but not the right side so this case never happens.

Comment: Sounds good.  +1 from me.

Comment: @Errol.Y You need to add the analysis of that case to the answer for it to be correct and complete

Answer (score 2):

As Batominovski pointed out in his comment, $a$ and $b$ have to be positive integers, otherwise there are counterexamples to the statement.

We're going to use the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44835/133781) [identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112788/133781):

i) $ab=[a,b](a,b)$ where $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ denotes the $\text{lcm}$ and the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$, respectively.

ii) $[ca,cb]=c[a,b]$.

We have $(a,a+5)\mid (a+5)-a=5$, so $(a,a+5)=1$ or $(a,a+5)=5$. Analogously, $(b,b+5)=1$ or $(b,b+5)=5$. So we have four cases to analyze:

I) $(a,a+5)=(b,b+5)=1:$ By the first identity we deduce that $$a(a+5)=[a,a+5]=[b,b+5]=b(b+5).$$ Now, if $a>b$, then $a(a+5)>b(b+5)$ and if $a<b$, then $a(a+5)<b(b+5)$, therefore it must be $a=b$.

II) $(a,a+5)=1$ and $(b,b+5)=5$. Let's write $b=5b'$, then $b+5=5(b'+1)$. On the other hand, by the first identity we have $$a(a+5)=[a,a+5]=[b,b+5]=[5b',5(b'+1)]\overset{\text{by (ii)}}=5[b',b'+1]=5b'(b'+1).$$

Thus, $5\mid a(a+5)$, so $5\mid a$ and then $5\mid a+5$, contradiction; or $5\mid a+5$ and then $5\mid a$, contradiction again.

III) $(a,a+5)=5$ and $(b,b+5)=1$. By the symmetry of $a$ and $b$ this case is analogous to the previous one.

IV) $(a,a+5)=(b,b+5)=5$. Using the first identity we deduce that $$a(a+5)=5[a,a+5]=5[b,b+5]=b(b+5).$$

So, if $a>b$ or $a<b$ we will have $a(a+5)>b(b+5)$ or $a(a+5)<b(b+5)$, respectively. Hence, it must be $a=b$.

Comment: The second link actually goes to the proof of the identity $(ca,cb)=c(a,b)$, but since $\gcd$ and $\text{lcm}$ are dual, the same idea to prove the above identity can be applied to prove the identity ii).

Answer (score 0):

(1) $a \in \mathbb{N}, p \in \mathbb{P}: p \mid a \iff  gcd(a,a+p)=gcd(a,p)=p$

() $a \in \mathbb{N}, p \in \mathbb{P}: gcd(a,p) \neq p \iff gcd(a,p)=1$

"The gcd of a prime $p$ and a natural $a$ is $p$ if it is a divisor of $a$ and $1$ if it is not"

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}, p \in \mathbb{P}:$

(2)$$lcm(a,a+p)=\frac{a(a+p)}{gcd(a,p)}=\frac{b(b+p)}{gcd(b,p)}=lcm(b,b+p)$$

$(2) \land a \neq b \implies (p \mid a) \oplus (p \mid b)$.

Choose $p \mid a$ and $p \nmid b$:

$$\mathbb{N} \ni \frac{a(a+p)}{p^2}= \frac{1}{p} \frac{a(a+p)}{p} = \frac{lcm(a,a+p)}{p}=\frac{lcm(b,b+p)}{p}=\frac{b(b+p)}{p} \notin \mathbb{N}$$

Contradiction. $(2) \implies a=b$
(It so happens that $5 \in \mathbb{P}$)