# LCM and GCD in integral domain

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

In an integral domain, if `a|c` and `b|c` then `LCM(a,b)|c`? What if `GCD(a,b)=1` and `ac=bd`, may I assume that `a|d`?

I am needing to assure this for a demonstration but I can't prove or find an counterexample. What I'm willing to prove is that GCD exists if and only if LCM exists. I know that there is a similar question in the forum but I want to know what is above.

Comment: All integral domains do not have gcds and lcms.

Comment: How do you define lcm and gcd in an integral domain? I only know how to define them for principal ideal domains.

Comment: @Bernard I'm assuming that they exist in a certain Integral domain. I should have written it better, thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Joppy well, the question only stats that they exist. I've updated the description.

Comment: Re: your edit: that's not true. What is true is that $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b)$ exists $\iff \gcd(ac,bc)$ exists for all $\,c\neq 0\ \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque oh, so there is an error in the textbook we are using and in the proof I wrote hahaha. Thank you again! Now I have to check what mistake I've made so I could "prove" this.

Comment: @Bryant What is the textbook and page number? Maybe the assertion is that every pair of elements has a gcd iff every pair of elements has an lcm, which is true.

Comment: @BillDubuque The problem is: Suppose R is an integral domain and a, b ∈ R \ {0}. Show that gcd(a, b) exists if and only if lcm(a, b) exists. It's on page 66, exercise 3.1.18 of this textbook https://alistairsavage.ca/mat3143/notes/MAT3143-Ring_theory.pdf

Comment: @Bryant That claim is false, e.g. as [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37089/242) in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\,$ we have $\,a,b = 2,\,1\!-\!\sqrt{-3}\,$ have gcd $= 1$ but $\,\gcd(ab',bb') = \gcd(2\!+\!2\sqrt{-3},\,4)$ doesn't exist, so $\,\ell := {\rm lcm}(a,b)\,$ doesn't exist ( by the equivalence in my first comment). More explicitly, if the lcm $\ell$ existed then

$$2,b\mid 4,2b\,\Rightarrow\,\ell \mid 4,2b\,\Rightarrow\, \ell/2\mid 2,b\,\Rightarrow\, \ell/2 = 1\,\Rightarrow\, \ell = 2\,\Rightarrow\, b\mid 2\,\Rightarrow\,2\mid b'\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$$

Comment: @BillDubuque wow! Now I understand this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joppy, you can define the LCM of $a,b$ such as the LCM being the element satisfying (1.) $a|\text{lcm}(a,b), b|\text{lcm}(a,b)$ and (2.) $a|c, b|c \Rightarrow \text{lcm}(a,b)|c$, for $a,b,c$ elements of the integral domain. Similarly, the GCD must satisfy (1.) $\gcd(a,b)|a, \gcd(a,b)|b$ and (2.) $c|a,c|b \Rightarrow c|\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

> In an integral domain, if `a|c` and `b|c` then `LCM(a,b)|c`?

Yes, that follows by the [definition of LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) (assuming it exists), namely

$$ a,b\mid c\color{#c00}\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid c$$

> What if `GCD(a,b)=1` and `ac=bd`, may I assume that `a|d`?

Yes if ${\rm lcm}(a,b)$ exists [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44843/242) $\gcd(a,b)$ exists and $\gcd(a,b){\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab$

In particular we have $\gcd(a,b)=1\Rightarrow {\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab\,$ hence

$$a\mid bd\iff a,b\mid bd\color{#c00}\iff \underbrace{{\rm lcm}(a,b)}_{\textstyle ab}\mid bd\iff a\mid d,\ \ {\rm when}\ \ b\neq 0$$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Pehaps you could help me with a problem I've been turning around for hours---and it's driving me crazy---: prove that for a commutative, integral domain $D$, for all $a,b\in D$, if a, b have both a lcm and a gcd, then $\text{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)$ and $ab$ are associates. The proof should be only based on the definition of integral domain as well as of lcm and gcd.