# Show $\langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle = \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups

So I want to show that $\langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle = \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle$. My approach to this problem was to show a double containment, i.e. to show that $\langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle \subseteq  \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle$ and $ \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle \subseteq \langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle$.

I would like to see a full proof for this, specifically $\langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle \subseteq \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle$. (I tried it with the approach of breaking it down into to cases; $a$ has infinite order and $a$ has finite order, the latter of which i would appreciate the most help on.)

My approach to solving the whole problem: (I would appreciate any feedback on anything that is wrong, or a different approach to the proof.)

To show the easier containment, $\langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle \subseteq \langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle$, I did the following:
 Let $l = \operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$. Let $j \in \langle a^l\rangle$, so $j = (a^l)^k = a^{lk}$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. Since $l$ is a multiple of $m$ and $n$ by definition, we can say $l = ms = nt$ for some $s, t \in \mathbb Z$. Now $j = a^{kl} = a^{kms} = (a^m)^{ks} \in \langle a^m\rangle$. Similarly, $j = a^{kl} = a^{knt} = (a^n)^{kt} \in \langle a^n\rangle$. Now, since $j \in \langle a^m\rangle$ and $j \in \langle a^n\rangle$, it follows that $j \in \langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle$. Thus, by definition, $\langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle \subseteq \langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle$.

For the second containment, the one which I'm having more problems with, I attempted the following:

Case in which $a$ is infinite: Suppose that $\vert a \vert = \infty$. Let $c \in \langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle$. Then $c = a^{mx} = a^{ny}$ where $x, y \in \mathbb Z$. It follows that $a^{mx - ny} = e$ and so $mx = ny$ because if $mx  > ny$ then the difference would not be zero, and we would have an element that was finite, contradicting our hypothesis. And since $mx = ny$ we know $\operatorname{lcm}(mx, ny) = mx = ny$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(mx, ny)$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$. Hence $c \in \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle$ and thus $\langle a^m \rangle \cap \langle a^n \rangle \subseteq  \langle a^{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}\rangle$.

Case in which $a$ is finite: I tried starting it out the same as the previous case, but i could never reach my conclusion :(

Comment: Robert:May you show where this problem came from?

Comment: @Victor This problem does not require context to the level of source of the problem. Robert has elaborated enough for us to believe he has worked through this problem a bit and not merely worked his fingers on the `ctrl` keys. Further, this is not a problem that specialists' skills are required to track. This is a typical problem in a first course in group theory. Regards,

Comment: @Victor In any case 'Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications' by Thomas Judson, and Yes, this is a problem from an introductory course on the subject.

Comment: The $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ have dual definitions through their universal properties as follows: $$\forall n:\quad\begin{array}{c c}n|\gcd(a,b)\iff n|a~\wedge~n|b \\ a|n~\wedge~b|n\iff\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)|n.\end{array}$$ I saw these in a Bill D answer, and they make arguments for propositions like this pretty slick.

Comment: repeat: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82899/24430 , Also, it may help to try small examples. Maybe where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and then one where they are not.

Comment: @johnw.: Not quite a repeat; it's a "repeat" only in the case where $a$ is of infinite order, not in the case where it is of finite order.

Comment: In fancy terms, the lattice of subgroups of a cyclic group is isomorphic to the lattice of divisors of the order of the group.

Comment: In a similar vein, $<a^m,a^n>$ = $<a^{gcd(m,n)}>$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\def\lcm{\mathrm{lcm}}$Let $k$ be the order of $a$, with $k=0$ if $a$ is of infinite order. Note that $x\equiv y \pmod{0}$ is equivalent to $x=y$ (since $0|x-y$ if and only if $x-y=0$). Also, $\mathrm{lcm}(n,0) = \gcd(n,0) = n$.

Consider first the case with $n|k$ and $m|k$.

To show $\langle a^m\rangle\cap\langle a^n\rangle \subseteq \langle a^{\lcm(m,n)}\rangle$, let $x$ lie in the intersection. Then there exist $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=a^{mr} = a^{ns}$, so $mr\equiv ns\pmod{k}$. Thus, $k|mr-ns$, so $n|mr-ns$ and $m|mr-ns$. Therefore, $n|mr$ and $m|ns$. Since $n|mr$, then $mr$ is a common multiple of $n$ and $m$, hence is a multiple of $\lcm(m,n)$ (similarly with $ns$), so we can find $q$ such that $mr=q\lcm(m,n)$. Thus, $x = a^{mr} = a^{q\lcm(m,n)}\in\langle a^{\lcm(m,n)}\rangle$, as desired.

Now for the general case, note that $\langle a^n\rangle = \langle a^{\gcd(n,k)}\rangle$; thus, we are reduced to showing that $\lcm(n,m) \equiv \lcm(\gcd(n,k),\gcd(m,k))\pmod{k}$. This is true, but you may not have it in your arsenal yet, so here's a proof (that no doubt [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) can prove in a much slicker way):

> **Lemma.** $\lcm(\gcd(n,k),\gcd(m,k)) = \gcd(\lcm(n,m),k)$.

*Proof.* Indeed, $\gcd(n,k)$ and $\gcd(m,k)$ both divide $k$, hence their least common multiple divides $k$; and $\lcm(n,m)$ is a common multiple of $\gcd(n,k)$ and $\gcd(m,k)$, so $\lcm(\gcd(n,k),\gcd(m,k))$ divides $\lcm(n,m)$. Thus, the left hand side divides the right hand side. Conversely, let $p$ be a prime and suppose that $p^a$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $\gcd(\lcm(n,m),k)$. Then $p^a$ divides both $\lcm(n,m)$ and $k$, but $p^{a+1}$ does not divide at least one of them. Since $p^a$ divides $\lcm(n,m)$, then $p^a$ divides either $n$ or $m$, and we also know $p^a$ divides $k$. Either $p^{a+1}$ does not divide $k$, or it does not divide either $n$ or $m$. Thus, $p^a$ divides either $\gcd(n,k)$ or $\gcd(m,k)$, but $p^{a+1}$ divides neither. Therefore, $p^a$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $\lcm(\gcd(n,k),\gcd(m,k))$. $\Box$

Now the result follows: note that $\gcd(\lcm(n,m),k) \equiv \lcm(n,m)\pmod{k}$ (express $\gcd(\lcm(m,n),k)$ as a linear combination of $\lcm(m,,n)$ and $k$), so we are done.

Comment: It took me a while to work it through. I followed it for the most part, however I don't think I would have figured that out myself :( Thank You though!

Comment: @Robert: The difficulty is when you are not picking the "distinguished" generators for $\langle a^n\rangle$ and $\langle a^m\rangle$ (with $n|k$ and $m|k$); as you can see, the case where $n|k$ and $m|k$ follows pretty much like it does in the infinite case.

Comment: To Arturo Magidin: i have confusing about the difference between general case and the case where n|k and m|k, please help.

Comment: What is confusing about the difference? In one of them we assume $n|k$ and $m|k$; in the other we don't. For example, if $a$ has order $16$, we could have $n=6$ and $m=8$. What is it you are confused about, really?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Sorry to bring up such an old question, but what is a proof for p^(a)|lcm(m,n) implies p^(a)|m or p^(a)|n?  Intuitively it seems to make sense, but i havent found a proof yet (can't apply Euclid's Lemma if a>1).

Comment: @greycatbird: A proof depends on what you know/can apply. How do you define the least common multiple? How do you define the greatest common divisor? What properties about them do you know? Absent **context**, it’s hard to answer your question in a way that doesn’t end up wasting my time and yours by talking at cross purposes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Sorry. Adv. Undergrad w/ Intro. Elem. NT and Intro. Abstract Algebra courses. My attempt at proof: p^(a)|lcm(m,n)=mn/(m,n) implies p^(a)|mn (multiply both sides by g.c.d.). Can't necessarily use Euclid's lemma (if a>1), so i tried showing either (p^(a),m)=1 or (p^(a),n)=1 to show p^(a)|m or p^(a)|n. No luck yet.

Comment: @greycatbird: But how do you **define** the gcd and the lcm? Via their universal properties? With unique factorization? Have you established the connection between unique factorization and the gcd/lcm?

Comment: @Greycatbird: You can’t prove $(p^a,m)=1$ or $(p^a,n)=1$ because they don’t have be true: $p$ could divide both $m$ and $n$. But the highest power of $p$ that divides lcm$(a,b)$ can’t be larger than the greater of largest power dividing $n$ and largest power dividing $m$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I was using lcm(m,n)=mn/((m,n), but using the prime factorization definition, I think I get it. Certainly p^(b)|m and p^(c)|n for some b,c in {0,1,2,...} (it may even be that b=0 or c=0). It cannot be, however, that a>b and a>c, since p^(a)|lcm(m,n)=...p^max{b,c}... . If this were true, then p^(a-max{b,c})|lcm(m,n)/p^max{b,c}, which is impossible. Hence a<b or a<c. Therefore p^(a)|m or p^(a)|n.

Comment: @greycatbird: The prime factorization definition tells you that the power of $p$ that divides the gcd is the smallest of the largest power dividing $m$ and the largest power dividing $n$; and the power dividing the lcm is the largest of those two. But you can also deduce it from $mn=\gcd(m,n)\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$ by showing what is the largest power that divides $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: Upon trying to prove $\gcd(\text{lcm }(n,m), k)\equiv \text{ lcm }(n,m) \text{ mod }k$, as suggested, writing said gcd as a linear combination $\text{ lcm }(n,m)\cdot s +k\cdot t$, and reducing modulo $k$ leaves $s\cdot\text{lcm }(n,m)$. How is $s\cdot\text{lcm }(n,m)\equiv\text{ lcm }(n,m)\text{ mod }k$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Coming here from upanddownintegrate's question.  Note that $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m) \equiv \operatorname{lcm}(\gcd(n,k),\gcd(m,k))\pmod{k}$ is not generally true (an example from that question's comments: $n=2, m=3, k=11$ gives $6\equiv 1 \pmod{11}$).  However, you never needed to show that; instead you only needed to show exactly what you showed in the lemma.

Answer (score 9):

**Note** $ $ The equality in the lemma in Arturo's answer - that gcd distributes over lcm - can be derived simply via lcm, gcd laws. Rewriting lcms to gcds using $\rm\,[a,b] := lcm(a,b) =\: ab/(a,b)\,$ and clearing denominators, we deduce $\,\rm (k,[n,m]) = [(k,n),(k,m)]\,$ is equivalent to

$$\rm (k,m,n)\:(km,kn,mn)\ =\ (k,m)\:(k,n)\:(m,n)$$

whic is true, by both $\rm = (kkm,kkn,kmn,kmm,knn,mmn,mnn)\:$ by the distributive law. $ $ **QED**
For further details on the above gcd arithmetic [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242)

Dually, we could rewrite gcds to lcms, reducing it to the lcm dual of the above. And, of course, the dual identity is true: lcm distributes over gcd. These are well-known identities that come to the fore in the lattice viewpoint, e.g. see Birkhoff, *Lattice Theory*.

Though it is no longer needed after the above, it is instructive to note that Arturo's proof of lhs|rhs follows nicely from a useful lemma. First, recall the  [universal properties of lcm, gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242)

$$\rm\
 [a,b]\:|\:n \;\iff\; a,b\:|\:n\quad where\quad\: [a,b] := lcm(a,b) $$

$$\rm n\:|\:(c,d) \;\iff\; n\:|\:c,d\quad where\quad (c,d) := gcd(c,d) $$

Employing these we immediately deduce the following "lcm divides gcd" lemma

$$\rm [a,b]\ |\ (c,d)\iff a,b\ |\ (c,d)\iff a,b\ |\ c,d $$

Now, applying this to the particular values in Arturo's lemma we deduce

$$\rm [(n,k),(m,k)]\ |\ (k,[n,m])\iff (n,k),(m,k)\ |\ k,[n,m]$$

which is true: $\rm\:(n,k),(m,k)\ |\ k\:$ and $\rm\:(n,k)\ |\ n\ |\ [n,m],\:$ and $\rm\: (m,k)\ |\ m\ |\ [n,m]\quad$ **QED**