# How to solve this congruence class equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

how to solve for this equation in $\mathbb{Z}$12

$$
[8][x]+[3][y] = [9]\\
[6][x]+[5][y]=[2]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if it had a solution mod $12$ then [the solution persists](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) mod $2,\,$ where it is inconsistent.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3121751/242) for a simpler analogous *parity* contradiction, and motivation.