# Is there $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ a^2\equiv 2 \pmod3$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$ a^2\equiv 2\pmod3$$

I did the following : if the equation is true then one has
$(a-1)(a+1)\equiv1 \pmod3$ which implies that necessarly that both $(a-1)$ and $(a+1)$ are not even hence $a$ is an even number hence
$$a^2-2\equiv 0\pmod3$$
where $a^2-2$ is even, such that $a^2-2$ is a multiple of $3$ which is impossible!

Is my idea right ?

Comment: It's much common to use mod $3$ `\pmod3` rather than square brackets as they can mean equivalence class. Your argument is incorrect as $3$ divides $6$ (an even number), for instance.

Comment: And if you do indeed mean mod 3, it is a pretty easy process to just work through all of the relevant examples ($a=0,1,2$)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer or to massively overkill this, we have $(-1/3)=-1$ by quadratic reciprocity :p

Comment: @EeveeTrainer how's working with $a=0,1,2$ would help us prove there's no $a$ such that the equality holds ? and yes I meant mod by $[\cdot]$

Comment: If $a\equiv0 \pmod 3$, then what is the value of $a^2 \pmod 3$ ? If $a\equiv1 \pmod 3$, then what is the value of $a^2 \pmod 3$ ? If $a\equiv2 \pmod 3$, then what is the value of $a^2 \pmod 3$ ?

Comment: @Brian Parity arguments make sense $\!\bmod n$ only when $\,n\,$ is even, because generally [congruences only persist mod factors of the modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242).  Thus $\,a\equiv b\pmod{2n}\Rightarrow a\equiv b \pmod 2.\,$ Therefore, if a congruence has no roots $\!\bmod 2\,$ then it has none $\!\bmod 2n,\,$ e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3121751/242).

Comment: In particular, parity arguments won't help $\!\bmod n\,$ when $\,n\,$ is odd, e.g. if $\,x=a\,$ is a solution to $\,x^2 = b\pmod{\! n}\,$ then $\,x+n\,$ is another solution of *opposite* parity. Indeed by CRT the system $\,x\equiv j\pmod{n},\, x\equiv k\pmod{2}\,$ is solvable for any $\,j,k\,$ so the parity $\,k\,$ of $\,x\,$ implies nothing about the values  $\,j\equiv x\pmod{n}\, - $ they are completely independent generally (i.e. without any further hypotheses).

Comment: We can simply check for solutions. If $a\equiv0$ then $a^2\equiv 0$; if $a\equiv 1$ then $a^2\equiv 1$; and if $a\equiv 2$ then $a^2\equiv 4\equiv 1$. Since every integer is congruent to $0$, $1$, or $2$ in modulo $3$ arithmetic, we have exhausted all of the different possibilties, and so we conclude that the equation $a^2\equiv 2$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your disproof in that “evenness” is not something preserved mod 3 (or any other odd number).  For example, if $a = 6$, then $a^2 - 2 = 34$ is an even number, but “mod 3” reduces it to 1, an odd number.

I would use the “brute-force” solution suggested by Eevee Trainer's comment.  That is, if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, then one of the following must be true for some integer $k$:

- $a = 3k$
- $a = 3k + 1$
- $a = 3k + 2$

Now, work out the value of $(a^2 - 2) \mod{3}$ for each of these three cases, and see where it leads you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove this is as follows:

There is a well-known lemma in number theory which is as follows:

**Lemma:** If $p$ is a prime number with $p\equiv 3 \ (mod \ 4)$ and if $p|a^2+b^2$, then $p|a$ and $p|b$.

Now, since $a^2-2\equiv 0$ $(mod \ 3)$ and $a^2-2\equiv a^2+1$ $(mod \ 3)$, we get that $a^2+1\equiv 0$ $(mod \ 3)$ and thus by using this lemma for your case, we get that $3|a$ and $3|1$, which is impossible and thus it is done.