# Least natural $n$ such that $\,n \bmod 4\, =\, 3 + (n \bmod 34)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Question:** A number when divided by $4$ gives a remainder which is $3$ more than the remainder obtained on dividing the number by $34$.  Find the least such number.

**My approach:**
$$\begin{align} &n=34b+r,\quad\ \,  0\le r<34\\[.2em]
&n=4a+r\!+\!3,\,\ 0\le r+3<4\quad\Longrightarrow\quad r=0\end{align}$$

therefore we need a number which when divided by $34$ gives a remainder $0$, and a remainder of $3$ when divided by $4$.

$$34x=4y+3,$$
where $x$ and $y$ are integers

$$y=(8x)+(2x-3)/4,$$

I tried putting values of $x=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ but not getting an integer value for $y$.

Comment: Note that if a number is divisible by $34$ then it is even, whereas any number of the form $4k+3$ is odd.

Comment: $34x=4y+3$ has no integer solutions.

Comment: It is $\rm\color{#c00}{unsolvable}$, since by the standard [CRT Solvability Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) in the first linked dupe

$$\begin{align}  n&\equiv r\!+\!3\!\!\!\pmod{\!4}\\
n&\equiv r\quad\! \pmod{\!34}\end{align}\, \ \text{is solvable}\!\iff \underbrace{\gcd(4,34)\mid (r\!+\!3)-r}_{\textstyle{\rm i.e.}\ \ \  \color{#c00}{2\mid 3}\qquad\ }\qquad$$

Comment: Said equivalently, it is unsolvable because reducing the system $\!\bmod 2\,$ yields a parity contradiction: $\,r\!+\!1\equiv n\equiv r\pmod{\!2}.\,$ Such parity inconsistency is a prototypical example of the CRT Solvability Criterion - as explained at length in the similar example in the [2nd linked dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3121751/242).

Comment: There is nothing at all novel here. We already have plenty of examples of applying this criterion - many more illuminating. The question should be re-closed (and probably deleted too).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks : I vote to close in agreement with the above comments of Bill Dubuque. I have used the link in his first comment from above, referred to as the "first linked dupe" to mark this question as a duplicate. I invite someone else to close this question using the "second linked dupe" as a duplicate candidate , which can be found in Bill's second comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the least number $n$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
n\%34&\equiv& r,\\
n\%4&\equiv& r+3,
\end{eqnarray*}
Of course by definition
\begin{eqnarray*}
0\leq&n\%34&\leq33,\\
0\leq&n\%4&\leq3,
\end{eqnarray*}
from which it follows that $r=0$. Then $n=34x$ and $n=4y+3$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. But the former implies that $n$ is even, whereas the latter implies that $n$ is odd, a contradiction. Hence no such number exists.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand your sentiment, but I do not feel that this is a duplicate.

Comment: No, it *is* a dupe. That $\,r=0\,$ here is irrelevant since a parity contradiction arises for *any* $\,r,\,$ i.e. recalling that [congruences persist mod factors of the modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) (here the factor $2$) we infer $$\begin{align} n&\equiv \color{#c00}r\ \ \ \:\!  \pmod{\!34}\\
n&\equiv \color{#0a0}{r\!+\!3}\!\!\!\pmod{\!4}\end{align}\,\Rightarrow\, \begin{array}{} n\!\!\!\! &\equiv \color{#c00}r\ \ \ \ \ \pmod{\!2}\\  n\!\!\!\!&\equiv \color{#0a0}{r\!+\!1}\pmod{\!2}\\ \end{array}\qquad$$

Comment: Thus $\,\color{#0a0}{r\!+\!1}\equiv \color{#c00}r\pmod{\!2},\,$ contra successive integers have *opposite* parity (or, said equivalently, we deduce that $\, 0\equiv 1\pmod{\!2}\Rightarrow 2\mid 1\,$ by subtracting $\,r\,$ from both sides or prior congruence).

Comment: Above is essentially the same [prototypical parity example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3121751/242) that I gave in the 2nd dupe link, which is a special case of the proof of the general CRT solvability criterion given in the [1st dupe link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060713/deriving-chinese-remainder-theorem-from-gcd-bezout-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1) The presentation in the above answer *obfuscates the general essence of the matter*, i.e. that reducing the congruence pair mod their moduli gcd yields a necessary (& sufficient) condition for solvability.

Comment: well I don't know and not wish to interfere in this matter, but just to put up my opinion that the answer provided by @Servaes is easy to understand compared to the explanations given in the links referenced to.  As a person with not so much exposure to such high level of mathematics, this answer is fine for me.  Rest is up to the wishes of mods. Peace