# Find the greatest number that will divide 43, 91 and 183 so as to leave the same remainder in each case.

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

**I KNOW THIS IS SOLUTION BUT I DON'T KNOW WHY?**

We first find the difference of the numbers and then find the HCF of the got numbers.

183−91=92

183−43=140

91−43=48

Now find HCF of 92, 140 and 48, we get

92=2×2×23

140=2×2×5×7

48=2×2×2×2×3

HCF(92, 140, 48) = 4

Therefore, 4 is the required number.

**Can you explain how we get correct answer using this method.**

Answer (score 1):

Call the greatest number $n$ and the common remainder $x$, so our problem is

$$\begin{align}  
x&\equiv 43\pmod{n}\\
x&\equiv 91\pmod{n}\\
x&\equiv 183\!\!\!\pmod{n} \end{align}\qquad$$

By [general CRT theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1181523/242) this system is solvable iff pairwise solvable, i.e. iff

$$\begin{align} &n\mid 91\!-\!43,\, 183\!-\!91,\, 184\!-\!43\\
\iff \ \ &n\mid 48,92,140\\
\iff\ \  &n\mid \gcd(48,92,140) = 4\end{align}\ \ $$

where the final arrow is by the [gcd Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242).