# Prove $\langle a^s \rangle=\langle a^t \rangle \iff \gcd(n,s)=\gcd(n,t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups

> **Problem**
>
> Let $G$ be a cyclic group with $n$ elements and with $a$ as the generator let $b \in G$ and let $b=a^s$. Then $b$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $H$ of $G$ containing $\dfrac{n}{d}$ elements, where $d=\gcd(n,s)$. Also show that $\langle a^s \rangle=\langle a^t \rangle \iff \gcd(n,s)=\gcd(n,t)$

I could prove all the remaining parts of the problem but I can't figure out the way to prove the second part of the problem i.e. $\langle a^s \rangle=\langle a^t \rangle \impliedby \gcd(n,s)=\gcd(n,t)$ **without using the concept of Isomorphism.**

> The only things that can be used are,
>
> 1. Definition of cyclic group
> 2. The theorem that every cyclic group is abelian.
> 3. The theorem that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/988989/589.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any cyclic group has a $unique$ subgroup of the orders which are the divisors of its order. Since $gcd\ (n,s)=gcd\ (n,t)||G|$, hence there is a uniques subgroup in $G$ of the order $ \frac {n}{gcd(n,s)}=\frac {n}{gcd(n,t)}$ and hence $\langle{a^s}\rangle$=$\langle{a^t}\rangle$.

Comment: I want to know the proof the $uniqueness$ without using any concept of Isomorphism or Homomorphism.

Comment: @user170039 look at the following link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410389/subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group-and-their-order