# Proof verification: elementary Number Theory Proof of $am+bn = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Can anyone find a hole in my proof or tell me how to make it stronger or simpler? The "lemma above" referenced in the fourth paragraph is a small but solid proof showing that $r$ is strictly less than $b$ in the division algorithm if it's written $a=bq+r$.

> $\mathbf {Theorem}$ If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers that are relatively prime, then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $am+bn=1$.
>
> $\mathbf {Proof}$ Let $D = \{d \in \Bbb Z : am+bn>0\}$. Then there is a least element $l$ in D. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we need only show that $l$ divides $m$ and $n$.
>
> Suppose $l$ does not divide $m$. Then there are integers $q$ and $r$ such that $m=ql+r$. Rewritten, we have that $r=ql-m=q(am+bn)-m=qam-m+qbn=m(qa-1)+n(qb)$.
>
> Thus, $r \in D$. By the lemma above, $r<l$, contradicting that $l$ is the least element of $D$. We conclude then that $l$ divides $m$. Switching $m$ for $n$ gives the same result for $n$.
>
> Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $l=1$ and it follows that there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $am+bn=1$.

Comment: Have a look at this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215445/understanding-the-existence-and-uniqueness-of-the-gcd

Comment: @zwim Okay, I see. Are you implying that I still need to prove that any other common divisor of $m$ and $n$ divides $l$? I figured I didn't need to since we already know that they are relatively prime.

Comment: I didn't proofread your post in details, seemed ok, I just remembered having done it in details for any gcd (not just relatively prime numbers), so I linked it for you to have a comparison point.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I actually really appreciate that, it was just that link made think oh crap did I screw up? Thanks for your feedback, it's appreciated!

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242) for a more *conceptual* presentation of the standard proof of Bezout's GCD identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proof-verification:`

> The "lemma above" referenced in the fourth paragraph is a small but solid proof showing that $r$ is strictly less than $b$ in the division algorithm if it's written $a=bq+r$. `("the lemma" should be clearly stated before or after the proof.)`
>
> **Proof** `(Suppose m and n are two positive integers that are relatively prime.)` Let $D = \{d \in \Bbb Z : am+bn>0\}$. `(This set is ill-defined: what is the constraint for d?)` Then there is a least element $l$ in D. `(This is nontrivial. Can you explain?)` Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we need only show that $l$ divides $m$ and $n$. `(so that l must be 1, which is what we want to prove.)`
>
> Suppose $l$ does not divide $m$. Then there are integers $q$ and $r$ such that $m=ql+r$. `(There should be some properties about q and r that you need later.)` <s>Rewritten</s>`Rewriting it`, we have that $r=ql-m=q(am+bn)-m=qam-m+qbn=m(qa-1)+n(qb)$. `(Where is this rewritten formula used in the later argument?)`
>
> Thus, $r \in D$. By the lemma above `("the lemma" should be clearly stated before or after the proof.)`, $r<l$, contradicting that $l$ is the least element of $D$. We conclude then that $l$ divides $m$. Switching $m$ for $n$ gives the same result for $n$.
>
> Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $l=1$ and it follows that there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $am+bn=1$. `(This sentence is redundant.)`

The result you prove is called [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). See also a proof in the linked page.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! It's not too often that I get responses like this so I want to thank you for the effort you put into this. I have a couple of questions for you. The set $D$ is defined in that the constraint on $d$ is that it must be a positive integer such that $am+bn>0$. I'm wondering how I can define it better because that seems pretty clear cut to me.. as a beginner. The formula $m(qa-1)+n(qb)$ is used to show that $r \in D$. Perhaps the line break is confusing there...

Comment: The notation written in OP does not have the meaning you want. You could use (for fixed $m$ and $n$) $$D=\{d\in{\bf Z}: d=am+bn\, \hbox{ for some } a,b\in{\bf Z} \hbox{ and } d>0\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

suppose $\exists a,b\in Z;am+bn=1$

and we have $(m,n)=1$ (because $m$ and $n$ are positive integers that are relatively prime)

$d=(m,n)$ so $d|m$ and $d|n$

but $d|am+bn$ (according to $Theorem$:$\forall x,y\in Z; c|a \wedge  c|b \Rightarrow c|(ax+by)$

so $d|1$, but $d\in Z^*$ ($m$ and $n$ are positive integers)

so $d=1$