# Common divisors in a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, integral-domain

> Suppose that R is an integral domain and that α, β, γ ∈ R. We say that
>   γ is a common divisor of α and β if γ|α in R and γ|β in R. Suppose
>   that R is a PID. Suppose that α, β ∈ R. Let I = (α) and let J = (β).
>   Let K = I + J. Since R is a PID, we have K = (δ) where δ ∈ R. Prove
>   that δ has the following properties:

1. δ is a common divisor of α and β
2. If γ ∈ R and γ is a common divisor of α and β, then γ|δ in R

So for 1, I noted that I is contained in K and J is contained in K, so therefore β = δx for some x in R and α=δy for some y in R. Then it follows that δ divides α and β.

Then for 2, I supposed that γ is a common divisor of α and β in R. So again, β=γm and α=γn for some m and n in R. And then from part 1, β=δx=γm and α=δy=γn. This is where I get tripped up, because I was thinking about multiplying both sides by the inverses of m and n and then I realized that m and n aren't necessarily invertible elements. So I could use some help. And also, does my answer for #1 work?

Comment: Any thoughts about the two answers that have been posted?

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma\mid\alpha$ implies $\alpha$ is in $(\gamma)$ so $I\subseteq(\gamma)$; similarly, $J\subseteq(\gamma)$; then $(\delta)=I+J\subseteq(\gamma)$, so $\gamma\mid\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

$\gamma\mid\alpha,\beta \!\iff\! (\gamma)\supseteq (\alpha),(\beta) \!\iff\! (\gamma)\supseteq(\alpha)+(\beta)=(\delta) \!\iff\! \gamma\mid\delta$

Comment: **Remark**. Above is the  [*universal property*](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242) of the gcd $\,\delta = \gcd(\alpha,\beta).\,$ Note that $(1)$ follows from the direction $\,(\Leftarrow)\,$ with $\,\gamma = \delta.\ \  $