# Finding $\gcd(f,h)$ where $h$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, galois-theory

I am revising a little bit some Galois Theory using the book of P. Morandi, "Field and Galois Theory". I stack on the proof of *separability polynomials in characteristic $0$*, where he writes

> **If $f(X) \in  K[X]$ is irreducible over the field $K$, then the only possibility for $\gcd(f(X),h(X))$ is $1$ or $f(X)$.**

Well, say $g(X)=\gcd(f(X),h(X))$. So, $g(X)|f(X)$, thus $f(X)=k(X)g(X)$ for some $k(X)\in K[X]$. Since $f(X)$ is irreducible over $K$, it must be either $k(X)$ invertible, or $g(X)$ invertible. In other words, either $k(X)=c\in K\setminus \{0_K\}$, or $g(X)=1_K$ (since the gcd is monic). So, $g(X)=c^{-1}f(X)$ or $g(X)=1_K$.

**Why does the author claim that $g(X)=f(X)$ in the first case?**

*Thanks!*

Comment: Well you need to start saying that $f$ is monic too, so you obtain $c=1$ by looking at the coefficient of the highest degree

Comment: I would clearly agree, but the author doesn't assume that $f$ is monic too. But I can see that this is necessary. Do I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure that your deifnition and the author's of gdc agree? Because by the way you have written it it says either gcd is a unit or gcd is $f$. If gcd is always monic then $f$ is monic too

Comment: I searched this, but it is nowhere stated clearly in the text...

Comment: They're either using the widespread convention that gcds in $K[x]$ are normalized to be *monic*, or else  the common abuse of language with gcds where $\,\gcd(a,b) = c\,$ (or the gcd "is" $c)\,$  means that the gcd is *associate* to $c$, i.e. $\,\gcd(a,b) \approx c,\,$ esp. used in domains where there is no natural choice for unit-normalization, cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1199957/242) in the linked dupe, and [other related answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22unit%20normalization%22%20gcd).

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez Thanks for both the answer and the comments.

Comment: @BillDubuque Actually the answer I was looking for was only for these lines, that is whether the author had a mistake/typo here or whether I was missing something. Anyhow, thanks for extending my question and for the useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in arbitrary rings there is no canonical choice of the $\gcd$. In the first known rings that have $\gcd$ such as $\mathbb Z$ or $K[X]$ one usually says "gcd is positive" or "gcd is monic". However, $-2$ as (from the perspective of divisibility)  $\gcd$ of $4$ and $6$ as $2$ is. An example of a ring in which there is not a natural way to pick a $\gcd$ is the ring of Gaussian Integers $\mathbb Z[i]$.

For this reason, usually one says that $\gcd(a,b)$ (when it exists) is the set of all $c$ such that $c \mid a$, $c \mid b$ and $c$ is maximal with this property. In particular (when your ring is an integral domain), two $\gcd$ differ by multiplication by a unit. In this context, your text would be better written as something like this: if $f$ is irreducible then for all polynomials $h$ either $f$ is a $\gcd$ for $f$ and $h$ or $1$ is a $\gcd$ for $f$ and $h$, and written like this your proof is correct.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).