# What does it mean when you get a constant remainder when finding the gcd of 2 polynomials in a finite field mod n?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Use the Euclidean Algorithm to find the GCD of $3x^2+1$ and  $x+1$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

What I got was this:

$3x^2+1 = (x+1)(3x-3) + 4$

$x+1 = (4)(4x+4) + 0$

Since 4 was the last non-zero remainder, that is our GCD for the two polynomials. But, what does this mean?

Comment: You can apply the remainder theorem to conclude that $4 = 3 \cdot (-1)^2 + 1$.

Comment: Oh! So, then it is remainder 1 and thus the two polynomials are prime?

Comment: yeah since any non zero constant is a unit you have that their $gcd$ is $1$ so they are relatively prime

Comment: $4=-1$ is a unit (invertible) in $\Bbb Z_5$ so the gcd (unit) normalizes to $1,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1199957/242) in teh linked dupe.

Comment: thank you all for the clarification!

Comment: @mathnoob The remainder is indeed 4, not 1. You calculated it correctly. If you wished to compute the gcd, you would continue with the Euclidean algorithm by taking the remainder of $x + 1$ divided by $4$, which would give you a remainder of zero. This would enable you to conclude that $4$ is the gcd, which is equivalent to saying 1 is the gcd since the gcd is defined only up to multiplication with a unit.